# In gitk, why is my yellow button above master?

Tags: git, version-control, gitk

I couldn't find any documentation on gitk about what the colors mean, but the problem here I think is that my yellow button has passed my master. Now when I try to do:

`git push origin master`

It doesn't work. How did my yellow button get over master and how do I get them back together so I can do push origin master?

Comment: I don't use gitk, but what does 'git push origin master' tell you?

Comment: TML, it just says: Everything up-to-date. It's ignoring the latest commit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looks you need to put that commit back into the `master` branch (if it belongs there). Also it looks like you’ve detached HEAD because that commit is not a branch head. If all this is true, try the following:

```
# git log -1
```

Remember the commit ID.

```
# git checkout master
# git reset --hard <commit-id>
```

Now `gitk` will show the yellow commit right next to the `master` marker and `git push` will be working again.

As to how you got into that situation, the only thing I can imagine is that you used `git reset` to reset the `master` branch to a previous commit but have not changed the currently checked-out commit.

Comment: Works for me. Thank you!