# How can I reconcile detached HEAD with master/origin?

Tags: git

I'm new at the branching complexities of Git. I always work on a single branch and commit changes and then periodically push to my remote origin.

Somewhere recently, I did a reset of some files to get them out of commit staging, and later did a `rebase -i` to get rid of a couple recent local commits. Now I'm in a state I don't quite understand.

In my working area, `git log` shows exactly what I'd expect-- I'm on the right train with the commits I didn't want gone, and new ones there, etc.

But I just pushed to the remote repository, and what's there is different-- a couple of the commits I'd killed in the rebase got pushed, and the new ones committed locally aren't there.

I think "master/origin" is detached from HEAD, but I'm not 100% clear on what that means, how to visualize it with the command line tools, and how to fix it.

Comment: Have you pushed the commits before the rebase?

Comment: @manojlds: Not sure what you mean. I pushed some time before the rebase, but not immediately before.

Comment: As in did you previously push the commits that you removed in the rebase -i.. From your answer I think not.

Comment: @manojlds: Correct. I only killed commits that were more recent than the most recent push.  (Although as I mentioned, I have since pushed, since I thought everything was OK)

Comment: Can you explain what you did in `I did a reset of some files to get them out of commit staging` part? sorry for the questions :)

Comment: @manojlds: Unfortunately I can't recall, which is why I was vague :) I remember doing something around unstaging commits that was the first I noticed the "detached HEAD" comment. Thanks for your answer below. Will attempt to learn from there.

Answer (score 2780, accepted):

First, let’s clarify [**what HEAD is**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) and what it means when it is detached.

HEAD is the symbolic name for the currently checked out commit. When HEAD is not detached (the “normal”<sup>1</sup> situation: you have a branch checked out), HEAD actually points to a branch’s “ref” and the branch points to the commit. HEAD is thus “attached” to a branch. When you make a new commit, the branch that HEAD points to is updated to point to the new commit. HEAD follows automatically since it just points to the branch.

- `git symbolic-ref HEAD` yields `refs/heads/master`
  The branch named “master” is checked out.
- `git rev-parse refs/heads/master` yield `17a02998078923f2d62811326d130de991d1a95a`
  That commit is the current tip or “head” of the master branch.
- `git rev-parse HEAD` also yields `17a02998078923f2d62811326d130de991d1a95a`
  This is what it means to be a “symbolic ref”. It points to an object through some other reference.
  (Symbolic refs were originally implemented as symbolic links, but later changed to plain files with extra interpretation so that they could be used on platforms that do not have symlinks.)

We have `HEAD` → `refs/heads/master` → `17a02998078923f2d62811326d130de991d1a95a`

When HEAD is detached, it points directly to a commit—instead of indirectly pointing to one through a branch. You can think of a detached HEAD as being on an unnamed branch.

- `git symbolic-ref HEAD` fails with `fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref`
- `git rev-parse HEAD` yields `17a02998078923f2d62811326d130de991d1a95a`
  Since it is not a symbolic ref, it must point directly to the commit itself.

We have `HEAD` → `17a02998078923f2d62811326d130de991d1a95a`

The important thing to remember with a detached HEAD is that if the commit it points to is otherwise unreferenced (no other ref can reach it), then it will become “dangling” when you checkout some other commit. Eventually, such dangling commits will be pruned through the garbage collection process (by default, they are kept for at least 2 weeks and may be kept longer by being referenced by HEAD’s reflog).

<sup>1</sup>
It is perfectly fine to do “normal” work with a detached HEAD, you just have to keep track of what you are doing to avoid having to fish dropped history out of the reflog.

---

The intermediate steps of an interactive rebase are done with a detached HEAD (partially to avoid polluting the active branch’s reflog). If you finish the full rebase operation, it will update your original branch with the cumulative result of the rebase operation and reattach HEAD to the original branch. My guess is that you never fully completed the rebase process; this will leave you with a detached HEAD pointing to the commit that was most recently processed by the rebase operation.

To recover from your situation, you should create a branch that points to the commit currently pointed to by your detached HEAD:

```
git branch temp
git checkout temp
```

<sub>(these two commands can be abbreviated as `git checkout -b temp`)</sub>

This will reattach your HEAD to the new `temp` branch.

Next, you should compare the current commit (and its history) with the normal branch on which you expected to be working:

```
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit master origin/master temp
git diff master temp
git diff origin/master temp
```

(You will probably want to experiment with the log options: add `-p`, leave off `--pretty=…` to see the whole log message, etc.)

If your new `temp` branch looks good, you may want to update (e.g.) `master` to point to it:

```
git branch -f master temp
git checkout master
```

<sub>(these two commands can be abbreviated as `git checkout -B master temp`)</sub>

You can then delete the temporary branch:

```
git branch -d temp
```

Finally, you will probably want to push the reestablished history:

```
git push origin master
```

You may need to add `--force` to the end of this command to push if the remote branch can not be “fast-forwarded” to the new commit (i.e. you dropped, or rewrote some existing commit, or otherwise rewrote some bit of history).

If you were in the middle of a rebase operation you should probably clean it up. You can check whether a rebase was in process by looking for the directory `.git/rebase-merge/`. You can manually clean up the in-progress rebase by just deleting that directory (e.g. if you no longer remember the purpose and context of the active rebase operation). Usually you would use `git rebase --abort`, but that does some extra resetting that you probably want to avoid (it moves HEAD back to the original branch and resets it back to the original commit, which will undo some of the work we did above).

Comment: Interesting from `man git-symbolic-ref`: "In the past, `.git/HEAD` was a symbolic link pointing at `refs/heads/master`. When we wanted to switch to another branch, we did `ln -sf refs/heads/newbranch .git/HEAD`, and when we wanted to find out which branch we are on, we did `readlink .git/HEAD`. But symbolic links are not entirely portable, so they are now deprecated and symbolic refs (as described above) are used by default."

Comment: This answer was the final step that helped me get my origin/master back in sync with my local after accidentally doing a git reset --hard <sha> in Eclipse. The first step was to do a git reflog and recover the local commits (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1). Thank you.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that "HEAD is the symbolic name for the currently checked out commit" is very slightly inaccurate, because in a bare repo, there is no checked out commit, yet there is HEAD, and git even refuses to delete a branch in a bare repo pointed to by HEAD.

Comment: I made the, unfortunate, mistake of thinking "hey, I'll just be EXTRA SPECIAL specific when naming the branch that I want to point to temp..." and I did typed "git branch -f origin/master temp". Moral of the story, DON'T DO THAT. It ends up creating a new, local, branch named "origin/master" and created a host of other problems. This stemmed from a misunderstanding of how branch -f works and the difference between local branches and remote branches. Local branches track remote branches.

Comment: I agree with @AntonioSesto: for most projects (even fairly large ones) you don't need the mind-boggling complexity that is Git. My brain rebels at grappling with something that is so clearly over-engineered. I don't need it, and I don't want it.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think there is no need for the temp branch (although I usually use one my self).  `git branch -f master HEAD && git checkout master` is enough -- assuming your goal is to keep your current head but to designate it as `master`.  Other goals also make sense, and call for other recipes.

Comment: @JasperSprengers, git is "the stupid content tracker."  :)  It's not over-engineered for *anything*.  I use it for *everything*, from simple one-off repositories to store *single documents* I'm writing (anything long enough to go through a drafting process, I put in a git repo), all the way to complex collaborative projects with thousands of files.

Comment: Lol at the comment gurning about length. Whereas the rest of us simply scan through till we reach the line that says "To recover from your situation [...]", and go from there - while making a mental note that there's a useful well-explained backstory that we can read on a rainy day. The _option_ to read more does not hurt you, but it _does_ stand to benefit others.

Comment: I would argue that if you are following a good branching strategy then stuff like this really doesn't happen.  So, make sure to have a good strategy in place before doing anything :)

Comment: Don't follow the steps above blindly as you may lose your work! And certainly don't add `--force`

Comment: `It is perfectly fine to do “normal” work with a detached HEAD, you just have to keep track of what you are doing to avoid having to fish dropped history out of the reflog.` 

Thought I was reading a douglas adams novel for a second.

Comment: @Chris, re "This is what it means to be a symbolic ref". Yet it is possible for HEAD and Master to both point to x without HEAD being symbolic of Master.

Answer (score 673):

Just do this:

```
git checkout master
```

Or, if you have changes that you want to keep, do this:

```
git checkout -b temp
git checkout -B master temp
```

Comment: This is a dangerous response. People arriving at this answer have different states and "just do this to fix it" responses don't answer questions. This one can easily destroy work.

Comment: !"git checkout master" will cause all changes to be lost if the detached head is not part of master !!

Comment: I don't understand this. `git checkout master` solved it, but why? My `HEAD` was ALREADY at the latest master commit. The HEAD didnt change after this command. Why was a checkout needed then?

Comment: @Blauhirn You probably had the commit checked out, not the branch. The branch still points to the same commit, but you're in a different 'mode'.

Comment: `git reset` should come with a warning "If you have no idea what you're doing, stop it". Just recovered from an hour of terror thinking I'd lost the last week of work. Thanks!

Comment: isn't `git checkout -B master` dangerous? Because it basically resets master branch (or whatever existing branch) and discard all commits made before revert, unless they know what they are doing.

Comment: I tried `git checkout origin/master`, but that didn't work. How is this different from `git checkout master`? And why does this work?

Comment: Agree with @Archonic
It is important to understand how git works before you blindly run any commands. You can save time by not reading the big answer, but can lose more time if your work is lost.

Comment: When you are working submodules, you probably lost all the new commits just pulled.

Comment: @Archonic Yep, this answer just destroyed my work. But it helped me too since I made a backup when I sensed the risk. Thanks Daniel Alexiuc!

Comment: As someone who has to use basic git functions on a daily basis but doesn't really know what they are doing, I find taking a copy when things start to get cocked up saves a lot of tears. That way if/when your work gets lost into the ether you can always resort to cherry picking your work out and recommitting it as if you'd just created it.

Comment: I did `git checkout master` then  I got warned that two commits are *attached to no branch* so I did `git checkout <new-branch> <latest-of-the-two-commits>` and then `git merge <new-branch>`. And that did the trick

Answer (score 157):

I ran into this issue and when I read in the top voted answer:

> HEAD is the symbolic name for the currently checked out commit.

I thought: Ah-ha! If `HEAD` is the symbolic name for the currenlty checkout commit, I can reconcile it against `master` by rebasing it against `master`:

```
git rebase HEAD master
```

This command:

1. checks out `master`
2. identifies the parent commits of `HEAD` back to the point `HEAD` diverged from `master`
3. plays those commits on top of `master`

The end result is that all commits that were in `HEAD` but not `master` are then also in `master`. `master` remains checked out.

---

Regarding the remote:

> a couple of the commits I'd killed in the rebase got pushed, and the new ones committed locally aren't there.

The remote history can no longer be fast-forwarded using your local history. You'll need to force-push (`git push -f`) to overwrite the remote history. If you have any collaborators, it usually makes sense to coordinate this with them so everyone is on the same page.

After you push `master` to remote `origin`, your remote tracking branch `origin/master` will be updated to point to the same commit as `master`.

Comment: git: "First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded master to HEAD."
me: "nice!"

Comment: this suggestion created all sorts of parallel universes FML

Comment: Yikes. Sorry to hear that. Consider finding the commit your want to reset your branch to using `git reflog` then reset your branch to that commit with `git rest —hard $commit`

Comment: This is very nice and does exactly what I need for my workflow, but actually a little different from what I think is described here under point 3: it plays the commits between the divergence point and `master` on top of the detached `HEAD`. In other words, the commits naively done on the detached `HEAD` are exactly where I intended them to be, namely somewhere in history and not on top of `master`. I would normally use interactive rebase for this. Side note: `git rebase master HEAD` does the opposite and plays the commits on the detached `HEAD` on top of `master`, as described in this answer.

Answer (score 90):

Look here for basic explanation of detached head:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Command line to visualize it:

```
git branch
```

or

```
git branch -a
```

you will get output like below:

```
* (no branch)
master
branch1
```

The `* (no branch)` shows you are in detached head.

You could have come to this state by doing a `git checkout somecommit` etc. and it would have warned you with the following:

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You
>   can look around, make experimental
>   changes and commit them, and you can
>   discard any commits you make in this
>   state without impacting any branches
>   by performing another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to
>   retain commits you create, you may do
>   so (now or later) by using -b with the
>   checkout command again. Example:
>
> git checkout -b new_branch_name

**Now, to get them onto master:**

Do a `git reflog` or even just `git log` and note your commits. Now `git checkout master` and `git merge` the commits.

```
git merge HEAD@{1}
```

Edit:

To add, use `git rebase -i` not only for deleting / killing commits that you don't need, but also for editing them. Just mention "edit" in the commit list and you will be able to amend your commit and then issue a `git rebase --continue` to go ahead. This would have ensured that you never came in to a detached HEAD.

Comment: Thanks for the detail and great information pointers here. Seems like an explicit merge wasn't necessary, but this visualized some concepts I'll go back to. Thanks.

Answer (score 46):

### Get your detached commit onto its own branch

Simply run `git checkout -b mynewbranch`.

Then run `git log`, and you'll see that commit is now `HEAD` on this new branch.

Comment: If I do this, does `mynewbranch` attach to anything?

Comment: Yes, it attaches to where the detached head would have been attached, which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

I found this question when searching for `You are in 'detached HEAD' state.`

After analyzing what I had done to get here, as compared with what I had done in the past, I discovered that I had made a mistake.

My normal flow is:

```
git checkout master
git fetch
git checkout my-cool-branch
git pull
```

This time I did:

```
git checkout master
git fetch
git checkout origin/my-cool-branch
# You are in 'detached HEAD' state.
```

The problem is that I accidentally did:

```
git checkout origin/my-cool-branch
```

Rather than:

```
git checkout my-cool-branch
```

The fix (in my situation) was simply to run the above command and then continue the flow:

```
git checkout my-cool-branch
git pull
```

Comment: Perfect solution.

Comment: @user664833 Thanks for this perfect answer. Indeed something similar happened to me as well.

Comment: Worked in my case too

Comment: It seems that I did the same accident as you. Thanks for pointing out and sharing your experience here! :)

Answer (score 25):

If you want to push your current detached HEAD (check `git log` before), try:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

to send your detached HEAD into master branch at origin. If your push gets rejected, try `git pull origin master` first to get the changes from origin. If you don't care about the changes from origin and it's rejected, because you did some intentional rebase and you want to replace origin/master with your currently detached branch - then you may force it (`-f`). In case you lost some access to previous commits, you can always run `git reflog` to see the history from all branches.

---

To get back on a master branch, while keeping the changes, try the following commands:

```
git rebase HEAD master
git checkout master
```

See: [Git: "Not currently on any branch." Is there an easy way to get back on a branch, while keeping the changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4735556/55075)

Comment: This indeed sends the detached commits to origin/master. To attach the head to the local branch do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17667057/776345

Comment: When I do this I get This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/post-checkout.

Answer (score 24):

if you have just master branch and wanna back to "develop" or a feature just do this :

```
git checkout origin/develop
```

Note: checking out **origin/develop**.

You are in **detached HEAD** state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout...

then

```
git checkout -b develop
```

It works :)

Comment: What has worked for me is not 'git checkout origin/develop' but 'git checkout develop'. Using 'origin/develop' has always resulted in no changes, thereby remaining in "HEAD detached at origin/develop". Skipping the 'origin' part fixed everything.

Answer (score 14):

The following worked for me (using only branch master):

```
git push origin HEAD:master
git checkout master        
git pull
```

The first one pushes the detached HEAD to remote origin.

The second one moves to branch master.

The third one recovers the HEAD that becomes attached to branch master.

Problems might arise at the first command if the push gets rejected. But this would no longer be a problem of detached head, but is about the fact that the detached HEAD is not aware of some remote changes.

Comment: didn't work, I got: This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/pre-push. AND You are not currently on a branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.

Answer (score 13):

I just ran into this issue today and am pretty sure I solved it by doing:

```
git branch temp
git checkout master
git merge temp
```

I was on my work computer when I figured out how to do this, and now I'm running into the same problem on my personal computer. So will have to wait till Monday when I'm back at the work computer to see exactly how I did it.

Comment: @StarShine Kenorb fixed it. Now it saves your detached commits to a new branch, temp, switches to master, and merges temp into master.

Comment: I don't know why ppl are downvoting this, it fixed my problem stat but you may want to include the delete temp branch command.

Answer (score 9):

If you are completely sure HEAD is the good state:

```
git branch -f master HEAD
git checkout master
```

You probably can't push to origin, since your master has diverged from origin. If you are sure no one else is using the repo, you can force-push:

```
git push -f
```

Most useful if you are on a feature branch no one else is using.

Answer (score 8):

All you have to do is 'git checkout [branch-name]' where [branch-name] is the name of the original branch from which you got into a detached head state.  The (detached from asdfasdf) will disappear.

So for example, in branch 'dev' you checkout the commit asdfasd14314 ->

```
'git checkout asdfasd14314'
```

you are now in a detached head state

'git branch' will list something like ->

```
* (detached from asdfasdf)
  dev
  prod
  stage
```

but to get out of the detached head state and back to dev ->

```
'git checkout dev'
```

and then 'git branch' will list ->

```
* dev
  prod
  stage
```

but that is of course if you do not intend on keeping any changes from the detached head state but I find myself doing this a lot not intending to make any changes but just to look at a previous commit

Answer (score 6):

As pointed by Chris, I had following situation

`git symbolic-ref HEAD` fails with `fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref`

However `git rev-parse refs/heads/master` was pointing to a good commit from where I could recover (In my case last commit and you can see that commit by using `git show [SHA]`

I did a lot messy things after that, but what seems to have fixed is just,

`git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master`

And head is re attached!

Comment: Thanks!  My head had gotten detached.  I could catch it up to master but they just happened to be pointing at the same commit rather than head pointing to master which pointed to the commit.  Good tip =D

Answer (score 5):

Instead of doing `git checkout origin/master`

just do `git checkout master`

then `git branch` will confirm your branch.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to save changes made on detached head simply do this: make temporary branch and commit it with your changes done and then go to YOUR-BRANCH and merge the temp with it. Finally, delete temporary branch.

```
git checkout -b temp
git add . && git commit -m 'save changes'
git checkout YOUR-BRANCH
git merge temp
git branch -d temp
```

Answer (score 4):

For me it was as easy as deleting the local branch again, since I didn't have any local commits that I wanted to push:

So I did:

```
git branch -d branchname
```

And then checking the branch out again:

```
git checkout branchname
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I have resolved it by going through the following steps.

**If you need to keep your changes**

1. First you need to run `git checkout master` command to put you back to the master 
   branch.
2. If you need to keep your changes just run `git checkout -b changes` and 
   `git checkout -B master changes`

**If you don't need your changes**

1. To removes all untracked files from your branch run `git clean -df`.
2. Then you need to clear all unstaged changes within your repository. In order to do that you have to run `git checkout --`
3. Finally you have to put your branch back to the master branch by using `git checkout master` command.

Answer (score 3):

If you did some commits *on top of master* and just want to "backwards merge" `master` there (i.e. you want `master` to point to `HEAD`), the one-liner would be:

```
git checkout -B master HEAD
```

1. That creates a new branch named `master`, even if it exists already (which is like moving `master` and that's what we want).
2. The newly created branch is set to point to `HEAD`, which is where you are.
3. The new branch is checked out, so you are on `master` afterwards.

I found this especially useful in the case of sub-repositories, which also happen to be in a detached state rather often.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem today, where I had updated a submodule, but wasn't on any branch.  I had already committed, so stashing, checkout, unstashing wouldn't work.  I ended up cherry-picking the detached head's commit.  So immediately after I committed (when the push failed), I did:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick 99fe23ab
```

My thinking went:  I'm on a detached head, but I want to be on master.  Assuming my detached state is not very different from master, if I could apply my commit to master, I'd be set.  This is exactly what cherry-pick does.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, the detached HEAD state means **you are not checked out to HEAD (or tip) of any branch**.

### Understand With an Example

A branch in most of the cases is sequence of multiple commits like:

**Commit 1:**
master-->branch_HEAD(123be6a76168aca712aea16076e971c23835f8ca)

**Commit 2:**
master-->123be6a76168aca712aea16076e971c23835f8ca-->branch_HEAD(100644a76168aca712aea16076e971c23835f8ca)

As you can see above in case of sequence of commits, your branch points to your latest commit. So in that case if you checkout to commit *123be6a76168aca712aea16076e971c23835f8ca* then you would be in detached head state since HEAD of your branch points to *100644a76168aca712aea16076e971c23835f8ca* and technically you are checked out at HEAD of no branch. Hence, you are in the detached HEAD state.

### Theoretical Explanation

[In this Blog](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/08/git-tip-of-week-detached-heads.html) it's clearly stating
a Git repository is a tree-of-commits, with each commit pointing to its ancestor with each commit pointer is updated and these pointers to each branch are stored in the .git/refs sub-directories. Tags are stored in .git/refs/tags and branches are stored in .git/refs/heads. If you look at any of the files, you'll find each tag corresponds to a single file, with a 40-character commit hash and as explained above by @Chris Johnsen and @Yaroslav Nikitenko, you can check out these references.

Answer (score 1):

When I personally find myself in a situation when it turns out that I made some changes while I am not in `master` (i.e. `HEAD` is detached right above the `master` and there are no commits in between) stashing might help:

```
git stash # HEAD has same content as master, but we are still not in master
git checkout master  # switch to master, okay because no changes and master
git stash apply  # apply changes we had between HEAD and master in the first place
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is create a new branch,

```
git checkout -b new-branch-name
```

then check your commit logs by command,

```
git log
```

if everything matches then quit by :q

now push all your changes to new branch by command

```
git push --set-upstream origin new-branch-name
```

Now, problem resolved and your local git HEAD attached to new branch, you can raise pull request from portal.

Answer (score 0):

I got into a really silly state, I doubt anyone else will find this useful.... but just in case

```
git ls-remote origin
0d2ab882d0dd5a6db93d7ed77a5a0d7b258a5e1b        HEAD
6f96ad0f97ee832ee16007d865aac9af847c1ef6        refs/heads/HEAD
0d2ab882d0dd5a6db93d7ed77a5a0d7b258a5e1b        refs/heads/master
```

which I eventually fixed with

```
git push origin :HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I ran `git status`, and I saw that I had a few untracked files in my working directory.

To make the rebase work, I just had to clean them (since I didn't need them).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) in Eclipse:
assume your master is your main development branch

- commit you changes to a branch, normally a new one
- then pull from the remote
- then right click the project node, choose team then choose show history
- then right click the master, choose check out
- if Eclipse tells you, there are two masters one local one remote, choose the remote

After this you should be able to reattach to the origin-master.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me perfectly:

1.`git stash` to save your local modifications

If you want to discard changes 
`git clean -df` 
`git checkout -- .` 
git clean removes all untracked files (warning: while it won't delete ignored files mentioned directly in .gitignore, it may delete ignored files residing in folders) and git checkout clears all unstaged changes.

2.`git checkout master` to switch to the main branch (Assuming you want to use master) 
3.`git pull` to pull last commit from master branch 
4.`git status` in order to check everything looks great

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

Answer (score 0):

For people stumbling upon this question because checking out their `master` or `main` branch suddenly causes a detached HEAD state.

I had this issue because there was a tag called `main`. After deleting the tag locally and remotely I was able to checkout the `main` branch again and all normal git operations worked again.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I stash my changes with 
`git stash` and hard reset the branch in local to a previous commit(I thought it caused that) then did a `git pull` and I am not getting that head detached now. Dont forget `git stash apply` to have your changes again.

Answer (score -2):

```
git checkout checksum  # You could use this to peek previous checkpoints
git status # You will see HEAD detached at checksum
git checkout master # This moves HEAD to master branch
```