# Go to a particular revision

Tags: git, revision, revision-history

I cloned a Git repository of a certain project. Can I turn the files to the initial state and when I review the files go to revision 2, 3, 4 ... most recent? I'd like to have an overview of how the project was evolving.

Answer (score 1259, accepted):

**Before executing** this command, keep in mind that it will leave you in a **detached head status**.

Use `git checkout <sha1>` to check out a particular commit.

Where `<sha1>` is the commit unique number ([SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash value) that you can obtain with `git log`.

Here are some options after you are in the detached head status:

- Copy the files or make the changes that you need to a folder outside your Git folder, check out the branch where you need them `git checkout <existingBranch>` and replace files
- Create a new local branch `git checkout -b <new_branch_name> <sha1>`

---

Note: to "undo" (return from) the detached head state, simply use:

`git checkout <branch>` (where `<branch>` is e.g. `master`).

Comment: And is there a way I can find out in which revision the project is? I tried to checkout to the first commit with it's sha1 and I'd like to confirm I'm really there and what the sha1 of next commit will be.

Comment: You can do this `git log -n1`. But unless `git checkout` failed, it's a waste of effort.

Comment: It works. I had to use full sha1 (not partial). And if I want to put the project to second revision? `git log` shows only the first commit now, can I find out the sha1 of the next commit?

Comment: You should only have to use enough of the sha1 to guarantee uniqueness. Perhaps you had an unlucky coincidence. Git has no concept of the "next" commit; history is a DAG with all arrows pointing backwards. You should run `git log --oneline` and stick the output into a text file for reference (the abbreviated sha1 sums it provides are guaranteed to be unique). Another option, if your history is linear, is to figure out how many commits there are from the first commit till `master` and use `git checkout master~543` (if there are 543 commits), then `git checkout master~542`, etc.

Comment: I'm now in the first revision, so when I run `git log --oneline` I can see only one commit, should I clone the repository again? Then run `git log --oneline > commits.txt` and then use file commits.txt as a reference? Isn't it a little cumbersome?

Comment: No, just `git log --oneline master`.

Comment: Note: That does not remove directories, so you might see empty version7-related directories even though the files are those of version5. It can be surprising.

Comment: and how to checkout back to the current commit from "git checkout <sha1>"?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Checkout the branch.

Comment: @MarceloCantos i meant to say was, after the checkout, how does one return to the main branch or go back to the commit that they were originally on? I'd assume its `git checkout master` or some other branch depending where you are working?

Comment: Ah, now I see; I misplaced the implied comma. Yes, that's right, git checkout can be used to go to whichever commit you want, by id, tag, branch, or any of a number of other methods to specify a commit.

Comment: found so many complex responses for this in other threads. Yet this simple statement does it all. ;) Thanks

Comment: You should probably add what to do when *`error: pathspec '866e452bdb859' did not match any file(s) known to git`* is encountered on a valid commit. Its kind of amazing GitHub can find it but local Git cannot.

Comment: what is `<sha1>` here?

Comment: After doing the checkout you may also wish to go back to the latest as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin

Comment: @Den-Jason there's a lot of content on that question. What exactly are you referring to? In any event, going back to the latest is as simple as `git checkout -`.

Comment: @MarceloCantos it's the answer from Daniel Alexiuc.  The `git rev-parse` stuff provided by Chris Johnsen was useful too.

Comment: Does this mean that it will checkout the branch where that sha was originally committed and also bring the state of the checked out branch to that particular commit?

Comment: `git checkout -b <new_branch_name> <sha1>` :  to check out the commit to a branch.

Comment: If the git command isn't "seeing" that commit ( shat1 ) that you are trying to checkout, ie: pushed by someone else up to GitHub, you may need to do a `git fetch <origin or other remote location >` to update your local revisions.  Also, once its checked out you may want to do a `git checkout -b <new branch name>` to create a working/feature branch from it.

Comment: fyi sometimes the files are not fully updated for some mysterious reason. I found out that going to the root of the git project and running `git checkout <branch-name> .` fixed that issues.

Answer (score 87):

To go to a particular version/commit, run the following commands. You can get HASH-CODE from `git log --oneline -n 10`:

```
git reset --hard HASH-CODE
```

**Note** - After resetting to a particular version/commit, you can run `git pull --rebase`, if you want to bring back all the commits which are discarded.

Comment: Note that a `reset` doesn't just checkout a particular point in the graph it will also move your currently checked out branch

Comment: Also with `reset`, all your pending changes are discarded.

Comment: --hard flag will delete any commits after said hash.... probably want to add that little tid bit here. I'm sure people have lost history and wondered why.

Comment: `git pull --rebase` works only if you have a remote for your repo *and* it's up to date.

Comment: fyi sometimes the files are not fully updated for some mysterious reason. I found out that going to the root of the git project and running `git checkout <branch-name> .` fixed that issues.

Answer (score 23):

You can get a graphical view of the project history with tools like `gitk`. Just run:

```
gitk --all
```

If you want to checkout a specific branch:

```
git checkout <branch name>
```

For a specific commit, use the [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash instead of the branch name. (See [Treeishes](http://book.git-scm.com/4_git_treeishes.html) in the *Git Community Book*, which is a good read, to see other options for navigating your tree.)

`git log` has a whole set of options to display detailed or summary history too.

I don't know of an easy way to move *forward* in a commit history. Projects with a linear history are probably not all that common. The idea of a "revision" like you'd have with SVN or CVS doesn't map all that well in Git.

Comment: Be aware: git will not lie to you by giving you a single linear history of the project. That is unless the project actually evolved that way.

Comment: Moving forward is logically meaningless (even in a linear history), since a commit makes no reference to the "future". At best, you can identify all commits that have the commit in question as a parent. Mind you, moving backward isn't a trivial exercise either, due to merges.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Well, that's not entirely true. `git log -p -m --first-parent --reverse` will do a really good job of showing you a linear and accurate mainline history of changes since the beginning, with changes from merged history shown summarized in a single diff.

Answer (score 6):

Using a commit's [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) key/hash value, you could do the following:

- First, find the commit you want for a specific file:

  `git log -n <# commits> <file-name>`

  This, based on your `<# commits>`, will generate a list of commits for a specific file.

  ***Tip***: if you aren't sure what commit you are looking for, a good way to find out is using the following command: `git diff <commit-SHA1>..HEAD <file-name>`.  This command will show the difference between the current version of a commit, and a previous version of a commit for a specific file.

  ***Note***: a commit's SHA-1 key is formatted in the `git log -n`'s list as:

  > commit `<SHA1 id>`
- Second, checkout the desired version:

  If you have found the desired commit/version you want, simply use the command: `git checkout <desired-SHA1> <file-name>`

  This will place the version of the file you specified in the staging area.  To take it out of the staging area simply use the command: `reset HEAD <file-name>`

To revert back to where the remote repository is pointed to, simply use the command: `git checkout HEAD <file-name>`

Answer (score 4):

To get to a specific committed code, **you need the hash code** of that commit. You can get that hash code in two ways:

1. Get it from your [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab), or [Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) account.
   (It's on your commit URL, i.e., github.com/user/my_project/commit/**commit_hash_code**), or you can
2. `git log` and check your recent commits on that branch. It will show you the hash code of your commit and the message you left while you were committing your code. Just copy and then do `git checkout commit_hash_code`

After moving to that code, if you want to work on it and make changes, you should make another branch with `git checkout -b <new-branch-name>`. Otherwise, the changes will not be retained.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a situation where we have a *master* branch, and then another branch called *17.0* and inside this 17.0 there was a commit hash number, say **"XYZ"**. And the customer is given a build till that XYZ revision.
Now we came across a bug and that needs to be solved for that customer. So we need to create a separate branch for that customer till that "xyz" hash value.
So here is how I did it.

First I created a folder with that customer name on my local machine. Say the customer name is "AAA",
once that folder is created, issue the following command inside this folder:

1. **git init**
2. **git clone**  After this command, you will be on the *master* branch. So switch to the desired branch
3. **git checkout 17.0** This will bring you to the branch where your commit is present
4. **git checkout** : This will take your repository till that hash commit. See the name of your branch. It got changed to that commit hash number. Now give a branch name to this hash value
5. **git branch ABC**: This will create a new branch on your local machine.
6. **git checkout ABC**
7. **git push origin ABC**: This will push this branch to the remote repository and create a branch on the Git server.
   You are done.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create all commits ever made to patches. Check out the initial commit and then apply the patches in order after reading.

Use `git format-patch <initial revision>` and then `git checkout <initial revision>`.
You should get a pile of files in your directory, starting with four digits which are the patches.

When you are done reading your revision, just do `git apply <filename>` which should look like `git apply 0001-*` and count.

The Git manual also gives me this:

> ```
>  git show next~10:Documentation/README
> ```
>
> Shows the contents of the file Documentation/README as they were current in the 10th last commit of the branch next.

You could also have a look at `git blame filename` which gives you a listing where each line is associated with a commit hash + author.