# Download specific Chromium revision source code

Tags: git, chromium, chromium-embedded

I am using CEF3 to build an application. I have encountered a bug and thus debugging requires some Chromium source code.

I have managed to use https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/how-tos/get-the-code and downloaded what I think is the latest source code. However CEF uses revision 33.0.1750.170 and the source code has a total of almost 15gb on my machine - I think this is because git downloads all file history.

Could somebody please provide me with instructions of how I can download just the 33.0.1750.170 files or how I could use my current download to maybe checkout that revision into another directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git - go to particular revision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539130/git-go-to-particular-revision)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the git repo cloned, you can do something like this:

```
git checkout tags/33.0.1750.170
```

This is because Chromium "tags" their releases, as documented on the page you linked.

Once you do that, your working directory will contain the code for the requested release.  There's no way to clone only that release, you need to get the entire 15 GB first, then go to the revision you want.

Use `git tag -l` to list all available tags.  See [Download a specific tag with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/download-a-specific-tag-with-git)

Comment: Is that a problem?  If I understand you correctly, this is not unexpected, it's just how Git works.

Comment: If all you want is a working directory and no project history then just `rm -rf .git` after the checkout command