# Last version of git branch that uses a deprecated variable

Tags: git, github

I need to install the most recent branch of a program that uses a deprecated variable. How can I do so?

I tried using

```
git grep <variable>  $(git rev-list --all)
```

but it 1) only outputs commit hash values and 2) does not gives the last branch.

Comment: Commits don't have names, they are identified by hashes. It's very unclear what your asking or want to do. If you have a hash you can [check that out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539130/go-to-particular-revision)

Comment: I fixed it to a branch

Comment: The goal eventually is to checkout the branch with the deprecated variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
git grep <variable>  $(git for-each-ref refs/heads refs/remotes/origin --format="%(refname)")
```

The `git for-each-ref` command returns branches (by `refs/heads`) and remote branches (by `refs/remotes/origin`). `git grep` tries to find the keyword from the tip of these branches.