# How to amend last 2nd commit or specific commit only

Tags: git

In my current branch, I've 2 commits which are not pushed yet.

```
mainlineBranch:
 commit 2 - recent commit
 commit 1
```

I've few code changes & want to amend only to commit 1 without deleting commit 2. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539130/go-to-particular-revision Will this answer your question? Check out the specific commit make your changes, and append to the commit?

Comment: Thanks, It worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go to particular revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539130/go-to-particular-revision)

Answer (score 1):

`git rebase --interactive` helps you.

First, stash your uncommitted changes for later use (`git stash`). Your working directory should be clean now. Run `git rebase -i HEAD~3` and your editor will pop up with the following content:

```
pick  aaaaaaa
pick  bbbbbbb
pick  ccccccc
```

In the above example, `bbbbbbb` should be your "commit 1" and `ccccccc` should be your "commit 2". Change `pick` into `edit` for `bbbbbbb` and exit the editor. You can then `git stash pop` the changes onto the working tree, which should be at commit 1 now. Amend commit 1 with `git commit --amend` and continue the rebase with `git rebase --confinue`. Assume conflicts are handled, you should now land on a new HEAD with a modified commit 1' and an identical commit 2'.