# On git, I checked out a previous commit and now can't find my later commits

Tags: git

I am very new to git usage and finding it very confusing to understand the branch/commit management. Anyway, the project I am working on is managed by git, and I am using gitk for it. Using gitk I was making commmits, and checked out a previous commit. And now when I do **Visualize HEAD's history**, the commit that I checked out appears last and my other 5 or 6 commits after that have disappeared.

Please note that I was working on master branch - but for some reason I was not on master branch right Now. That is to say the gitk visualization was like this:

commit 14
.
.
.
commit 9
.
.
master
.
.
.
.
commit 1

I checked out commit 9 and I don't have any commits hash codes either.

Comment: Helpful trick with gitk: `gitk --all` (shows all branches).  That way, no matter which one you're on, or even if you're in that "detached HEAD" state, you can see everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use git log to see all your commits, get the SHA1 hash of the lastest one, then do

```
git checkout -b "branchname" <SHA1 goes here>
```

This will retrieve any commits you made when not on a checked out branch and you should then have all your commits visible on a new branch.

Comment: Git log is displaying commits up till the current commit that I have checked out. It's not showing the ones I did after it.

Comment: Okay I just did that. Thankfully it shows all the commits and their hashes too. It shows All 53 commits and shows the latest one next to HEAD{0}. And that's a checkout, so I will just checkout the one below this one. But can you, for the love of God, tell me what just happened? And how can I get my master to point to this latest commit?

Comment: I think you may have been in 'detached head state' (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head), but I'm not sure how. Basically, make sure you are always checked out onto a named branch before committing. Git will record your commits in a tree structure, but will have no label (branch name) for the tip of the branch you are creating, so you can't find it.

Comment: So what do I do know? If I want to merge this head-less branch back to master?

Comment: If you just want to add those commits to master, use: 'git checkout master', followed by 'git merge <SHA1 of commit>'

Comment: Actually I was in a detached Head state. Creating a new tempt branch, resetting master to that branch, and then checking out master helped me sort that out.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin Was of GREAT help.

Answer (score 0):

You are in a detached HEAD state, meaning your current HEAD points to a commit and not a branch. What you need to do is to checkout the master branch again, then you will see your commits in gitk. Type the following in a command prompt:

```
git checkout master
```

Comment: Yeah - that was it. I had figured that out before. Thanks for pointing it for reference.