# Git update submodules recursively

Tags: git, git-submodules

My project struture

```
ProjectA
-FrameworkA (submodule)
--Twig (submodule of FrameworkA)
```

How I can update submodules recursively? I already tried some git commands (on ProjectA root)

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

or

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master
```

but cannot pull files of Twig.

Comment: How about [git-deep](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/git-deep)?

Answer (score 907, accepted):

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

You will also probably want to use the --init option which will make it initialize any uninitialized submodules:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

*Note: **in some older versions of Git**, if you use the `--init` option, already-initialized submodules may not be updated. In that case, you should also run the command without `--init` option.*

Comment: How about recursive add submodule? "git submodule add FrameworkA.git" just pull files of FrameworkA.

Comment: You can just do a "git submodule add blah" and then "git submodule update --init --recursive".

Comment: Is this different than my way below?

Comment: @Irineau The note about already-initialized submodules not being updated if `--init` is used does not match my experiences on Git 2.2.2. I see both top-level and nested submodules that have already been initialized getting the correct commit checked out when I use `git submodule update --init --recursive`, and I think the claim that you need to run the command with and without `--init` is simply wrong. Unless somebody can either show evidence that this is the behaviour or demonstrate that it's changed between versions and was once true, I plan to edit it out altogether.

Comment: @MarkAmery, I remember this being a problem in some version of git that I cannot remember. I just tested it in 1.9.3 and the problem does not seem to exist anymore. I updated the answer to refer to a vague "older versions". If anyone can specify which version changed this behavior, that would be great.

Answer (score 57):

The way I use is:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
git submodule foreach --recursive git fetch
git submodule foreach git merge origin master
```

Comment: I worked with changing the last line to: `git submodule foreach git pull --ff-only origin master`

Comment: I also would add --recursive to the last line: "git submodule foreach --recursive git merge origin master" otherwise you can get a dirty submodule when it itself has updated a submodule.

Comment: Been looking for this for the past three hours. Thank you sir.

To add to this, you can also use these commands for committing, such as:
`git submodule foreach --recursive 'git commit -a | :'`. The `:` makes it loop regardless of result. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728933/continue-looping-over-submodules-with-the-git-submodule-foreach-command-after)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728933/continue-looping-over-submodules-with-the-git-submodule-foreach-command-after.

Answer (score 26):

As it may happens that the default branch of your submodules are **not** `master` (which happens a lot in my case), this is how I automate the full Git submodules upgrades:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
git submodule foreach 'git fetch origin; git checkout $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); git reset --hard origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); git submodule update --recursive; git clean -dfx'
```

Comment: I tryed to add this command in my [generic Makefile](https://github.com/Falkor/Makefiles/blob/devel/repo/Makefile) yet I'm still stucked to make GNU Make *ignore* the interpretation of the $(...) sequence, despite it's presence within simple quotes. Anybody have an idea?

Comment: Your command is what I needed thank you! But I get: `Entering 'Core'
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` where `Core`
 is the submodule

Comment: Also, I guess you need to figure out this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/18008139/3383543

Comment: not having the recursive option means this only works if your submodules don't include submodules again.

Comment: This answer needs a warning for newbies: `reset --hard` and `clean -dfx`.

Answer (score 25):

In recent Git (I'm using v2.15.1), the following will merge upstream submodule changes into the submodules recursively:

```
git submodule update --recursive --remote --merge
```

You may add `--init` to initialize any uninitialized submodules and use `--rebase` if you want to rebase instead of merge.

You need to commit the changes afterwards:

```
git add . && git commit -m 'Update submodules to latest revisions'
```

Comment: This, I thought I was doing something wrong but your answer confirmed to me that
`git submodule update --remote my-dir/my-submodule`
works just as well

Answer (score 12):

How about

```
git config --global submodule.recurse true
```

and forget it?

See [the git book documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following to your `Makefile`:

```
submodule:
    git submodule update --init --recursive
    git submodule foreach 'git fetch origin; git checkout $$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); git reset --hard origin/$$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); git submodule update --recursive; git clean -dfx'
```

Then you can simple run `make submodule` everytime you want to update submodules.

Answer (score 0):

I had one submodule causing issues (the 'fatal:...' that Sanandrea reported, above). Navigated to the submodule and used 'git clean -dfx' resolved it.

Comment: If you're adding new information, could you complete your answer once you've fully solved the issue? "trying to use same" leaves me unsure whether this is an answer or just a comment.