# How to prevent GNU Make from interpreting a string?

Tags: makefile, gnu, gnu-make

As I mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168449/git-update-submodule-recursive/20363693#20363693), I generally upgrade my git submodules recursively as follows:

```
git submodule foreach 'git fetch origin; git checkout $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); git reset --hard origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); git submodule update --recursive; git clean -dfx'
```

This command works perfectly when invoked from a terminal. Now I have trouble to embed  it in GNU make as in the `upgrade` target of [this Makefile](https://github.com/Falkor/Makefiles/blob/devel/repo/Makefile). 
If I simply copy paste the command:

```
upgrade:
   git submodule foreach 'git fetch origin; git checkout $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); git reset --hard origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); git submodule update --recursive; git clean -dfx'
```

it does not work: GNU make tries to evaluate / interpret the `$(git ...)` section despite the presence of simple quotes. I tried several attempts without success so far (`$$\(git ...)`, defining a verbatim command [as explained here](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_6.html#SEC65) etc.).

Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only character that is special to make in a recipe is `$` (and backslash/newline combinations, but only backslashes before newlines, nowhere else).  Every other character is ignored and passed through to the command.

And, the only way to quote the `$` is by doubling it, to `$$`.

So, to quote `$(git rev-parse ...)` you just write `$$(git rev-parse ...)`.  No need for backslashes etc.  Just take the shell command and every `$` you want to use literally, everywhere in the string, ignoring ALL types of shell quoting, make it into `$$`.

Comment: looks like I missed the 'do not escape also the parenthesis' attempt that is indeed successful. Thanks ;)