# How to use SSH instead of HTTP for Git submodules?

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-submodules, git-clone

Why are people having this problem?

$ git clone --recursive git@github.com:acani/Chats.git
Cloning into 'Chats'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

https://github.com/acani/Chats/issues/53#issuecomment-118014684

I've read some answers that say to change the submodule URL from SSH to HTTP, but why should I have to do that. I don't want to do that. I want to keep it SSH so that I don't have to enter my username & password into Terminal if I want to push. Everyone can clone the SSH URL fine, so why can't they recursively clone it as a submodule?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957125/git-submodule-permission-denied

Comment: @ma1 Did I answered your question with the workaround I proposed below?

Comment: @VonC Sorry, I didn't try your workaround. I just switched from the SSH protocol to the Git protocol. Thank you for answering anyway though.

Comment: Without changing the `.gitmodules` file you could instead change your `~/.gitconfig` to use SSH instead of HTTP in URLs, as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62615597/3419541

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SSH protocol doesn’t support anonymous access to a Git repository.

So, don't use the SSH protocol. Instead, use either the Smart HTTP protocol (recommended) or the Git protocol.

For every submodule URL in your repository's `.gitmodules` file, replace `git@github.com:` with either `https://github.com/` (to use the Smart HTTP protocol) or `git://github.com/` (to use the Git protocol).

More info: [Git - The Protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)

Comment: So my answer is valid: use https instead of SSH for submodules

Comment: Exactly: my answer is about *not* changing anything, but still using the right protocol.

Comment: once we update the ssh urls to https urls in `.gitmodules` files what is the procedure that needs to be followed since even after updating to https urls I am unable to clone submodules with `git submodule update --init --recursive` command. I further checked that my main repo config file still has ssh url for the submodule.

Answer (score 8):

As a workaround, you can try using https url for any github repo:

```
cd myParentRepo
git config url.https://github.com/.insteadOf ssh://git@github.com/
# or
git config url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git@github.com:
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in the .gitmodules file:

```
url = git+ssh://git@github.com/path-to-repo
```

Note: In case you already have used `git submodule init` you have to sync with `git submodule sync`. That way the submodule url's will update accordingly and you can call `git submodule update` to try to fetch the repository again.