# Git auth failing when running npm install as sudo

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am trying to install an npm package that pulls from our private repo. When I run npm install as myself, I get `Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.` When I run it as sudo, I get

```
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

I normally don't use sudo to do npm install. I think the issue is that when I run as sudo, it is looking in /var/root/.ssh for the key. I don't have the root user credentials, otherwise I would create a new key as root. Is there another work around?

EDIT: tried the suggestions below, they didn't work. However, the repo in questions is referenced by a dependency below the package root. `./node_modules//package.json. If I change the git url to use http, it works, but it's not a good idea to do it this way because I'll have to change it when I check the package back into the repo.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the issue is that when I run as sudo, it is looking in /var/root/.ssh for the key. I don't have the root user credentials

A workaround would be to change the url of that repo to an http one: it would then query for your login/password instead of relying on ssh keys which you cannot provide as root.

```
cd /path/to/private/repo
git remote set-url origin https://server/user/repo
```

> If I change the git url to use http, it works, but it's not a good idea to do it this way because I'll have to change it when I check the package back into the repo.

Actually, you can change an url by another *without* modifying the config of the remote url.
For instance (as in [How to use SSH instead of HTTP for Git submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31185110/6309))

```
git config url.https://github.com/.insteadOf ssh://git@github.com/
# or
git config url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git@github.com:
```

Comment: OK, but how is that different from changing the config? I am creating a new file that will be checked into the repo, and I am telling the config to use a different url.

Comment: @MusicalShore because you can set it as global config (not changing the config of the repo itself: git config --global ...

Comment: That doesn't work either. I tried it as me and as sudo. In the npm output, I can see that it is still using ssh://

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`sudo /bin/bash` then, run your npm command

Comment: what's the error in this case? If you from you your user, let's say `mshore`, run `sudo /bin/bash` it should open a non-login terminal with root access but with `mshore's` environment. What happens when you do `sudo /bin/bash` from your repo's directory and then do `git pull` ?

Comment: alright, that means basically that you're `root` and that you're ssh keys are being loaded from your user. if after `sudo /bin/bash` you do `whoami` it should output `root`. Just FYI once you are into to the root bash, you don't need to do `sudo npm ...` anymore. Just `npm ...`.

Comment: The problem sort of went away on it's own, I may have inadvertently fixed it. However, I did look in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts and my key was in there.