# Subproject commit doesnt appear

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule, let's call it `my-submodule`. And two projects that use this submodule: `project-accounts`/ `project-proxy`.

What I did.

- In `project-accounts` I created new branch `feature-1` from remote `develop` branch for `my-submodule`. Did commit `commit-1` and pushed to this new branch (submodule).
- In `project-accounts` (in main project) I also create new branch, did some changes, then commit `commit-2` and push. In changes I can see that shared module now links to the new commits (hash was 1234567, now 7654321 - aka `commit-1`). Subproject commit appeared.
- In `project-proxy` I ran `git submodule update --recursive`. Then did `git pull origin feature-1`. Changes appeared. Now I want to make it so that this project also links to new commit in submodule. But when I perform `commit` git doesnt see any changes, so no subproject commit available.

How to fix it?

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19029685/8564999)

Comment: Better, this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032653/7976758 `git submodule update --recursive --remote`

Comment: @phd Can I choose remote branch with this command?

Comment: See [`git submodule update`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--ltpathgt82308203) and [`git submodule set-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-set-branch-b--branchltbranchgt--ltpathgt).