# After resetting branch to an older commit, how can I update submodules accordingly?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I had to reset a current branch to a previous commit. I did

```
git reset --hard prev_commit_id
```

When I did a `git status`, it shows that my submodules have changes not staged for commit, presumably because the submodules are newer than what I reset my branch to. I am wondering what is the proper way to also reset those submodules to whatever state they were in at `prev_commit_id`?

Comment: Did you tried `git checkout .` ?

Comment: @HassenGaaya Just tried it and it seems nothing happens to the submodules

Comment: I think what you need is `git clean -f -d`

Comment: @HassenGaaya I don't see how that's submodule related

Comment: [`git submodule update --init --recursive`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168693/7976758) Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+updates