# can't push upstream using EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I use EGit in eclipse to pull and push.

my config is:

```
  [remote "origin"]  
    fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    push = refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

local branch is master
Remote Tracking branch is origin/master

when I do push, it comes out "origin/master:master[up to date]". Actually the remote branch is not up to date. I wander if I configure the wrong way.

Sometimes I change different configure, I will get either "create a new branch"(which is wrong, as I just push some commits) or "reject-no fast forward"(which is strange, as I am the only user of the remote repository and I have already fetch before push)

[image: a busy cat]
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: I used to have another remote branch origin/master, which was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Check with Egit if you aren't in a [detached HEAD mode](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Resetting_to_a_Branch_or_a_Tag):

[image: checked out branches in EGit]

> If HEAD is "detached", i.e. is not pointing to the tip of a local branch but to a commit or tag, then none or several "checked-out" markers may appear in the tree, since any number of remote branch or tags may point to the currently checked out commit.
>   The state you are in while your HEAD is detached is not recorded by any branch (which is natural --- you are not on any branch).

(See "[Why did git detach my head?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)" for probable cause, and "[Git: How can I reconcile detached HEAD with master/origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)" for reconciliation).

That is a common cause for an "up to date" message when pushing to a remote repo.

Comment: I add some pictures. Do you still think I have a Detached Head?

Comment: I made the change the tree messy, and how can I avoid this happen. It should like a single chain.

Comment: @user1626792 you don't seem to be in a detached head, and your history is fine: it reflects the merge from remote to your repo (but your own repo history is linear).

Comment: @user1626792 However, you need to commit something in order to push it: right now, your HEAD doesn't reference any *new* commit compared to the remote.

Comment: the merged commit actually didn't contain any changes. it just what I have to do firstly, otherwise it would push successfully. But sometime when I do merge, it fails, and then could not push to the upstream.

Comment: Is this information useful to you. I don't when merge will fail. Is it just a bug of EGit?

Comment: @Jenny if the merge fails, it should fail because of conflict. Did you have issue resolving said merge conflicts? (http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#team_mergeconflicts)

Comment: When the merge fails, I will commit some new change, then do push to the upstream, sometimes it will successfully.

Comment: Hi, I add a new clue in the additional answer. would you like to help me with the problem to avoid it happen again.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After I push to upstream successfully, like version 0.3.9, I continue to change my codes locally and submit a version 0.5.0. This submit should based on version 0.3.9. I don't know why. That's why I have to do merge every time, and sometimes merge make my codes messy.

Comment: I guess you have pull it wrong. It should merge / rebase automatically when pull.