# why i cannot push mirror to github?

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-push

i can sync origin using

```
git fetch origin
```

i am on master branch, origin is a bare repo.

also i can run to push changes to github:

```
git push github  --all
git push github --tags
```

but why latest commits get using git fetch origin cannot be pushed to github?

when i push, git just replies with:
Everything up-to-date

**this means that push is in fact not happened :( since the latest commits fetched from origin is not pushed to github**, why?

// this is local mirror of origin, and i want to push it to github

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
        mirror = true
        url = http://git.mirror.xxx.xx/xxx/root.git
[remote "github"]
        url = git@github.com:username/xxx.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git fetch` will fetch all the remote tracking branches for `origin`.

But if those new commits don't concern your current local branch, `git push github` won't update anything regarding said (already up-to-date) current branch.
(depending on the [current git push policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586687/what-is-the-result-of-git-push-origin/9749477#9749477), and your git version)

You can try a `git push --mirror github`, in order to push all refs to GitHub.
But you will need first to **fetch** branches from github: `git fetch github`, in order for your local repo to know about said matching branches.

Comment: how to know it that commits concerns my current local branch? why git push --all cannot push it?

Comment: @thinke365 `git push --all` will follow the default push policy (`matching`, until git2.0): if you don't have remote tracking branch for github remote repo, it won't push anything. `git push --mirror`, on the other hand, follows: "Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end" (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

Comment: @thinke365 'git branch -a' will list all branches (remote tracking and local).

Comment: if you don't have remote tracking branch for github remote repo, what this means?

Comment: @thinke365 it means you might have to push those branches explicitly (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/git-how-to-create-remote-branch), or that you need to track them first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309

Comment: @thinke365 by the way, make sure you aren't currently with a "detached `HEAD`" in your repo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171261/cant-push-upstream-using-egit/12171567#12171567