# EGit not pushing, says it's already up to date

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I'm trying using git in eclipse for the first time, and I'm stuck. Brand new project, only one branch. I did the initial push to github, works great. Than I changed something, commited the change in my local git (shows in the history), but when trying to push, it's saying everything is up to date.

I have no idea what to do about it...

Comment: Personal advice: Throw away egit and use command line.

Comment: yes, I guess no other choice. it's totally broken

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/12171567/6309 help?

Comment: Is the branch something other than 'master'?

Comment: @nitind no, i just have a master branch, with the head at the top

Comment: Pushing and pulling using the same protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what was wrong. For some reason EGit messed up the directories, and kept the data not in the correct project's directory

Comment: Interesting to know. I have to remember to check that one next time. +1