# How to fix the pushing rejected and asked to pull when pulling results in "everything is up to date"?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Using EGit with Eclipse when I try to push my code into the remote repository I get an error message saying that I should pull first, as shown in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDag0.png).

[image: Error dialog when trying to push]

When I then try to pull from the remote repository I get a message saying that everything is up to date, as shown in Figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM6xE.png).

[image: Message dialog after pulling]

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried merging?

Comment: When I try using **Team / Merge..** and then selecting **origin/master** from **Remote Tracking** I get a _Multiple problems have occurred_ error dialog with the error message _Merge of revisions ... with base ... using strategy resolve resulted in: Failed._

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that:

- you are using the latest version of EGit (2.3+)
- you have stashed/commit everything before pulling (as in [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/367672/1014944/#msg_1014944))
- you are not in a detached head mode (as in "[can't push upstream using EGit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12171567/6309)")

---

The [OP Krige](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334569/krige) [adds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475258/how-to-fix-the-pushing-rejected-and-asked-to-pull-when-pulling-results-in-every/15476133#comment21914291_15476133):

> in the end I noticed a class file was mentioned in the `DIRTY_WORKTREE` error message.
>   I deleted that file from the file system, did a pull, resolved the conflicts and pushed.
>   Everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: I am using Eclipse 3.8.0 installed on Ubuntu through its Software Center. I installed EGit using "Install New Software" inside Eclipse and the version I got is 1.3.0

Comment: @Krige 1.3 for Egit? Seems a bit old.

Comment: I didn't choose it, that's the one I got using "Install New Software" inside Eclipse

Comment: @Krige but surely you can upgrade it?

Comment: It turned out I have used in Eclipse the wrong repository for EGit. I was using the Indigo main repository. I uninstalled EGit 1.3.0 and installed the newest version using the repository [link](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates). Now when I try to pull I get a dialog like in Figure 2, but now it gives me a `DIRTY_WORKTREE` message in the Failed Paths field.

Comment: @Krige right, hence the advice to commit or stash everything *before* the pull.

Comment: I did the commit but I still get the `DIRTY_WORKTREE` error. I don't know what you mean with _stash_. The link to the thread in the second item of the list in your answer is broken.

Comment: So in the end I noticed a class file was mentioned in the `DIRTY_WORKTREE` error message. I deleted that file from the file system, did a pull, resolved the conflicts and pushed. Everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: @Krige Excellent, I have added your conclusion to the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the DIRTY_WORKTREE issue and you are not able to delete the file (for whatever reasons), you should do a pull, or replace with HEAD and then add to Index. This will resolve the conflicts (assuming use of the merge tool) and you should then be able to commit/push your changes, or else pull again.