# EGit shows that local repository is ahead and behind the central repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, egit

I had to dive into using Git in a short period of time: so I set up a repository at Bitbucket, configured EGit at home and office. I suppose that as I've only read the first chapters of the Git documentation, so I messed things up quite quickly:

After a few commits and pushes I had a `[Master ↑4]` label next to the name of my project. I looked up that this means my local master is ahead of the central master by 4 commits. I tried to push the changes to correct this situation but I got a `master: master [rejected - non-fast-forward]` message without further explanations of what went wrong.

Then I decided to pull the changes with the idea that maybe I have to first get the changes I made on the other workstation before pushing local changes. This resulted in another error:

```
Fetch Result: No ref to fetch from origin - everything up to date.
Update Result: Failed / Failed Paths - DIRTY_WORKTREE ...
```

This added a down arrow next to the up arrow and now it says `[Master ↑4↓1]`

How is it possible to be both ahead and behind of the central repo? How to synchronize all repositories at this point?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/15476133/6309 help?

Comment: It wasn't the solution to my problem but it certainly put in me on track to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

1. Manually resolving DIRTY_WORKTREE problems
2. Committing all the changes
3. Pulling from the central repo to merge the changes
4. Pushing everything upstream

I don't know if this is the right workflow but all the arrows have disappeared and the latest version is now on Bitbucket.