# Find later changes to a file in git

Tags: git

I checked out a specific revision of a repository with `git checkout` after `git clone` (git tells me that I have a detached head, if that is important).Now, this revision doesn't compile completely. It looks like some refactoring was only done partially, and I need to see what changes have been done later.

I've tried

```
git diff origin/master -- path/to/file
```

but that treated my file as completely new. I get a diff like:

```
diff --git a/drivers/usb/core/driver.c b/drivers/usb/core/driver.c
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..19e1244
--- /dev/null
+++ b/drivers/usb/core/driver.c
(complete contents of the file follows)
```

which doesn't help me at all. I've also tried variations of `git log` with no success.

Ideally, I'd like to see all diffs of changes made to the file at later dates (compared to what I have in my working copy). Once I've found interesting ones, I'd like to look at all the changes made in the specific revisions.

Note: Just checking out a later revision or branch wouldn't work in my case. The project uses different branches for different devices, and I've already got the latest commit for the device I'm working on. There are newer commits where the refactoring is complete, but they don't have all the device specific stuff I need.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a <commit>:

```
$ git diff -h
usage: git diff [<options>] [<commit> [<commit>]] [--] [<path>...]
```

so if you provide the current commit (HEAD) and the one in the future it will show all differences affecting the specified file between your detached head and the remote head. ie:

```
git checkout HEAD~10
git diff HEAD origin/master -- path/to/file
```

moves me back 10 commits from my current position on master, creating a detached head and then shows all changes affecting that file between this current commit and the original commit. Of course `git diff HEAD~10 HEAD -- path/to/file` would have done it anyway from the usual case where HEAD == master.

Comment: Seems more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

As in "[Git: How can I reconcile detached HEAD with `master/origin`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)", you could first make a `temp` branch where your detached HEAD is, and then:

```
git diff origin/master temp -- /path/to/file
```