# How to retrieve the git branch name that was built by Jenkins when using inverse branch selection strategy?

Tags: git, plugins, jenkins, branch, inverse

We have one Jenkins job which builds every branch except master when there are new commits. This behavior can be configured via git plugin's 'choosing strategy:inverse' so that it listens to every branch except a specified branch.

This functions very nicely. But the problem is that GIT_BRANCH environment variable always refers to the excluded branch('origin/master' in our case). How to query the actual branch that was built by Jenkins?

Currently I am using a workaround that I grep it from generated changelog.xml. But it happens sometimes that changelog.xml is empty when Jenkins switches between different branches and I cannot find this info. What is the correct way of retrieving/querying from Jenkins the branch that was actually built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because git never checks out a branch just a commit directly you have to do the following:

To get the sha of the checked out commit:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

To get the all branches that commit is under:

```
git branch -a --contains SHA
```

The out put of the second command could look like this

```
master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/develop
```

Answer (score 18):

I successfully used this syntax:

```
GIT_BRANCH=`git rev-parse HEAD | git branch -a --contains | grep remotes | sed s/.*remotes.origin.//`
```

Comment: Great! For anyone else, I had to slightly adjust this to:

`git rev-parse HEAD | git branch -a --contains | grep remotes | sed -e 's/.*remotes.origin.//'`

for OS X

Comment: With master checked out in a repo I'm currently working with, this results in `HEAD -> origin/master\nmaster` (the `\n` is really a newline in the result), which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Note that --contains will also include branches that are newer than the currently checked out code.  This worked better for me: `git show-ref | grep $(git rev-parse HEAD) | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | sed -e 's/.*remotes.origin.//'`  And possibly pipe this to `head -n1` if you want it to arbitrarily pick the first branch name if there are multiple branches pointing to this commit.

Comment: Where can I use this in Jenkins? I can't seem to use it as an ant property.. where did you configure this to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a Jenkins bug? You can grab in your build script the name of the checked out branch with this:

```
git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD
```

Actually Jenkins has the working copy in detached HEAD, which is why `git branch` returns "no branch". See [this quite detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5772192/11343) for digging into reconciliation with between a detached HEAD and a branch.

Comment: Thanks Charles. That works in a normal git workarea but not in a jenkins workspace where command returns nothing. Running 'git branch' in jenkins workspace gives '*(no branch)'. Probably the chosen branch must be queried from Jenkins in some way as it seems to make the checkout based on commit-id in the chosen branch.

Comment: Yes, Jenkins works in detached HEAD. see my edit and the linked answer. I'm sure one of the commands linked in it should work.

Comment: This command works in CMD, but not in my Jenkins, why? C:\Tools\Jenkins\jobs\DevOps\jobs\Test-GitHub\workspace>git --version 
git version 2.7.0.windows.1
C:\Tools\Jenkins\jobs\DevOps\jobs\Test-GitHub\workspace>git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD 
C:\Tools\Jenkins\jobs\DevOps\jobs\Test-GitHub\workspace>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe how hard this is. I'm doing this for Jenkins as well. I piggypacked off Piotr Kuczynski's solution:

```
branch=`git rev-parse HEAD | git branch -a --contains | grep remotes | sed s/.*remotes.origin.//`
branch=`echo $branch | awk '{print $NF}'`
```

Because sometimes, as Matt Kantor pointed out, Piotr's solution gives a lot of junk back. But the last word in that junk appears to always be correct. Note that this solution only works if the ref you're using corresponds exactly with a branch that exists on remote (so local branches will not work).