# Github detached head for beginners -- how to resolve this situation?

Tags: git, github, repository

In a bit of a bind. Not as familiar with git but was using Github with Windows without issue. Until somehow, on the last commit, I must have done something horribly wrong and it resulted in a detached head.

Following the directions on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin), I saw that the first job is to create a temp branch, so I did the following:

> git branch temp
>
> git checkout temp

When I do that, I see a file needs a merge? And I see an error message about "needing to resolve your current index first"?

I also performed a `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit master origin/master temp`. It shows me that my commits are still there. What I see is below:

[image: The graph comparison]

How do I get back to where I need to be? I'm being overly cautious about this because I need to make sure I don't lose those commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting where you want to be is easy: `git checkout master`. This will however not include that commit that was apparently pushed to GitHub before but isn’t included in your master branch (that “WORKING. BOOM.” commit).

You should merge it into your master branch to include the commit and to make sure that nothing is lost on GitHub:

```
git merge temp
```

Afterwards, you can just push to GitHub:

```
git push origin
```

Comment: Great, this plus a little more phenagling did the trick. Thanks!