# Git push help after checkout to commit

Tags: git

I have made checkout to my previous version in my repo.

```
git checkout 9dc64fa
```

Then I have made few changes and made few commits.

Right now when I check status it says:

```
# HEAD detached from 9dc64fa
```

How do I need to make push to update data on the server with new commit?

Comment: I think this post will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin

Comment: What do you want to push? How would anybody pull your changes down, if you don't have a branch pointing to the commits you want to send to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commits are intended to go on a branch. This way you can easily get to its tip, where all the fun happens, with a simple command:

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

In your situation, you've made commits from an unnamed ref (to which you refereed by SHA-1), and git has no way to derive a branch name from that. To push as usual, first create a branch like this:

```
git checkout -b <new_branch_name>
```

If you actually wanted to commit to an already existing branch, you can still overwrite it, but do make sure that's really want you intend to do (check the `checkout` subcommand usage, or just delete the target branch beforehand).