# git status after checking out a previous commit

Tags: git

I wanted to rewind back several commits because some of my coworkers broke the build in their recent changes.  So I did

```
git checkout 7bb648abd7381bee5b92c18ff215b4f8a38935ee
```

Where 7bb648abd7381bee5b92c18ff215b4f8a38935ee is a commit four commits ago.

However, when I did

```
git status
```

it returned

```
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Why didn't it tell me that I was in the same branch but only four commits behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you've checked out a commit, not a branch. If you want to move the branch you should do, after your `checkout`:

```
git branch -f myBranchName #or "master" if it's the branch you're working on
```

it will move the branch `myBranchName` if it already exists.

However, beware: you're going to change a shared history, so make sure you warn every people working on this branch.

Note that Git won't let you push it so easily (to ensure you know what you're doing): you'll have to `push -f`

Comment: will that create a branch `myBranchName` that contains the baseline of that commit i checked out ?

Comment: you should replace `myBranchName` by the branch you're using. So, since you'll use an existing branch name, it will move your branch rather than creating one. It will indeed put the branch tag on the commit you've checked out.

Comment: how about if i just want to create a brand new branch with a baseline from a previous commit of an existing branch?

Comment: Then when you're on the wanted commit, just do `git branch myNewBranch` to create it (and afterwards `git checkout myNewBranch`, to work on this branch)

Comment: fantastic.  exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You are in a detached head state.  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5772882/1049112 for an excellent explantion of what it means to have a detached head.

Branches (and all heads) only point to a single commit.  You are not 'on' a branch unless you do a `git checkout <branchname>`.  Anytime you do another `git checkout <something else>` you are no longer on that branch.