# AndroidStudio and uncommitted changes to BitBucket

Tags: git, android-studio, bitbucket

I'm starting to use AndroidStudio and the BitBucked plugin.

The all concept off Git is new to me and I've already stumbled in a problem.

I've committed the changes using `VCS -> Commit changes` but when I got to the `Push` part, I've made something (probably hited the cancel button) and the `Push` wasn't made.

How can I push that uncommitted changes? I've searched all over the available options and can't see to figure it out.

If I go to `VCS -> Git -> Show History` I can see the commit and the affected files but can't figure how to push them to the BitBucket site.
[image]

Comment: You can't push uncommitted changes.  I suggest learning Git on the command-line.

Comment: Thanks. But is it lost?

Comment: The changes should still be there on your local repository unless you discarded them.  Did you run any other commands/menu options?

Comment: Nops. Did not do anything else

Comment: Check the files changed section. May be some files are not added to VCS so you can't commit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `GIT Gui` to `Amend Last Commit` and that lead me to a Detached HEAD` situation.

Solved my situation with [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5772882/1317865).