# how to move 1 commit forward

Tags: git, github

I created file example.txt and committed it.
After that i removed file with git rm example.txt. and committed changes
Then i used `git checkout HEAD^` which in my understanding. moving me to previous commit.
The file is back now and
Now when i use `git status`
i get following:

```
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

So i have two questions:
1. why right now i am not on any branch?
2. How i can return to 1 commit forward( where i removed file and committed changes).
Many thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why right now i am not on any branch?

Since you checked out a specific commit, you are in a [detached state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5772882/1330470) now.

> How i can return to 1 commit forward( where i removed file and committed changes).

In your particular case it should be as simple as `git checkout HEAD`

Comment: Did as you said. Same result. File still in directory and i still not on any branch.

Comment: My bad, try `git checkout <branch_name>` (branch name is probably master).