# Git Checking out a Commit

Tags: git

When I switch branches in git I use the `checkout` command.  There often arises a situation in which I want to simply go back and view the state of a project at a certain commit.  I've been using the `git checkout <commit hash>`.  This almost always leaves me in a state with a detached HEAD.

I was wondering if someone might be able to explain to me why we can checkout branches without detaching the head, but cannot checkout a specific commit in the same way without detaching the `HEAD` pointer? I have made the mistake of doing a `git reset` to view an old commit and this of course deletes everything that came after that commit.

**Why does `git checkout <commit hash>` detach the head?  And if this isn't the right command for what I am trying to do what is?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: How can I reconcile detached HEAD with master/origin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the primary purposes for `HEAD` is that it becomes the parent commit of any new commits you create. Typically the `HEAD` reference takes one of two forms - either a symbolic reference to a branch tip (e.g. `master`) or the hash of a specific commit. The first is the "normal" mode of operation, and a new commit results in 1) the parent of the new commit being set to the hash represented by the current `HEAD`, and 2) the branch reference that is the current target of the `HEAD` reference being moved to point to the new commit. The second case is called "detached", because your `HEAD` reference is not currently attached to a branch, but to a specific commit that may or may not be a branch tip. This is not a problem, but is just a reminder to you that, because you do not have a branch to update if you create a new commit, any new commits you do make will have nothing except `HEAD` pointing at them. If you then check out a different branch, there is nothing at all pointing at the new commits, so you run the risk of losing them (there's still the `HEAD` reflog, so you can generally recover even then, though).

So, the short answer is, no, there is no way to check out an arbitrary non-branch-tip commit without either detaching the `HEAD` or creating a new branch (but if you're just wanting to look at something on an older commit, that doesn't make sense, because you'll end up with many not-useful branches cluttering up your namespace. There's no harm in having `HEAD` detached, and it's a normal way of working within `git`. It just reminds you when you do things like `git status` so that you can keep in mind what you're in the middle of...

Comment: so say for example i checkout commit B in the sequence A -> B -> C -> D  would git checkout D "reattach" the head to the branch?

Comment: If by `D` you mean `git checkout master` instead of `git checkout 34627fe6756d` or whatever, yes. Checking out a branch by name will get you out of "detached HEAD" state. Checking something out by hash (even if it happens to be a branch tip) is what causes you to become detached (other things can, though as well, like `git checkout master^3` or `git checkout master@{3 days ago}` - basically anything that isn't just a simple branch name...).

Answer (score 1):

You do use checkout correctly. In git commits are in specific order. For example, this would be your typical history:

```
A - B - C - D  <-- branch master
  \ E - F      <-- branch feature
```

Not sure what the design decision was, but it's convenient. Branches always point to the last commit in a branch. So `checkout master` will get commit `D`, when `checkout feature` will get `F`. Because when you check out a branch - you are interested in it's current state and you (probably) want to continue working starting from the last change.

When you check out a single commit - you look something up and usually revert back. You rarely want to start doing something with commit `C`, because it has commit `D` after it (so `C` is basically "outdated"). If you want to base work off a certain commit - you can start a new branch from it with `git branch`.

Answer (score 1):

When you checkout a branch, you do detach the HEAD. You detach it from the branch you were working on. And you attach it immediatly to the branch you are going to. When you checkout a commit, there is nothing you can attach your HEAD to.