# How to return to a commit in detached branch

Tags: git

I was using a detached branch without know it, then i used **git commit -m <commit_name>**.

**Here the problem:**
I returned to a previous branch and when I wanted to return to what I had done, i couldn't find the branch or commit

Comment: "detached branch" is kind of a nonsense phrase in Git. Do you mean "detached HEAD"? (What does `git status` print?)

Comment: (if so, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/23160844/1256452)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git reflog` at rescue. Unreachable commits - those not reachable via any branch or tag - can still be `checkout`ed, as they are still in the local repository (at least during sometime, if `git gc` is not invoked).

You can locate the hash of your lost commit, the one committed in detached mode, inspecting the reflog:

```
git reflog
```

Once you locate it, do:

```
git checkout <hash_of_lost_commit>
```

And then create a new branch normally:

```
git checkout -b my_new_branch
```