# Having trouble pushing to GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-push

Doing `git push origin master` after making my commit says `everything up-to-date`, but when I go to my repository on GitHub, nothing has changed. I'm pretty new to Git, so does anyone know what's happening?

UPDATE: Nevermind, fixed it by making a new SSL key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by making a new SSH key.

Answer (score 1):

The OP mentions an ssh key issue, but if ssh is problematic, one can also switch to https:

```
git remote set-url https://myAccount@github.com/myAccount/myRepo
```

Then the password to enter would be the one of the GitHub account.

---

One case where you can make a commit locally, and a git push would say `everything up-to-date` is a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309):

Check if you are on a branch (or detached HEAD) by typing:

```
git branch
```

If none of the branches have a '`*`' in front of them, there is no current branch.
If that is the case, a `git checkout -b tmp` is enough to at least reference the detached commits.
See more at "[Git: How can I reconcile detached HEAD with `master/origin`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5772192/6309)"