# Can not do merge request on GitLab

Tags: gitlab

After updating GitLab from 6.2 to 7.1. I can not do merge requests. It tells me that there isn't anything to merge (but ofcourse there are).

[image: Merge request picture]

System info:

```
System information
System:     
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.1.2p95
Gem Version:    2.2.2
Bundler Version:1.6.5
Rake Version:   10.3.2
Sidekiq Version:2.17.0

GitLab information
Version:    7.1.1
Revision:   facfec4
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        <not showing>
HTTP Clone URL: <not showing>
SSH Clone URL:  <not showing>
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.9.6
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with repository/.git/config file. Nothing GitLab related.

Comment: What was the problem? I've run into a similar issue: comparing 'master' to 'foo' shows that foo has more recent changes but a merge request from 'foo' to 'master' shows that "There isn't anything to merge."

Comment: I have this problem too. please elaborate?

Comment: The problem I had is that this repository had weird branch name in it's git configuration, so I've changed it manually and problem went away

Answer (score 0):

Please check the log file githost.log

and you will understand it.

solution:

Just do this:

git checkout master

If that hasn't fixed it, this will:

git checkout -b temp

git branch -f master temp

git checkout master

Reference: [How can I reconcile detached HEAD with master/origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)