# GitLab: There isn't anything to merge. Branch and master are the same

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

I have been using `GitLab` to manage our Git repository. Recently I have encountered a problem where we are not able to create any pull requests. No matter the destination branch, I always get:

> There isn't anything to merge.
> Branch to be merged and master are
>   the same.

I have searched through stackoverflow where people had a same problem but I am still unable to resolve this issue. Can someone please point me right direction to resolve this issue?

...so far I have tried following:

[Can not do merge request on GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133398/can-not-do-merge-request-on-gitlab) --> Exactly same problem but I don't see anything weird in .git/config file!

[How can I reconcile detached HEAD with master/origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin) --> I don't have HEAD detached, I have verified.

[image: Error Message on GitLab]

Comment: Have you tried creating a fresh branch from master and then doing a PR?

Comment: git was updated to the version 2.3.0 a few days ago (2-5-2015), maybe can be related.

Comment: @TonyBarnes yes, I have tried all possible things. Removing local repository, re-cloning fresh copy, creating new brach from that, and doing a PR. Same issue. All my team mates getting same issue. None of us able to create PR. Thanks.

Comment: @3boll how can it be version issue? We are using "git version 1.9.3" and "GitLab 6.9.2 e46b644".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out this. There was a problem in [GitLab Satellites](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/development/architecture.md)! Restarted them fixed issue.

```
· February 10, 2015 16:57 -> ERROR -> Command failed [128]: /usr/bin/git --git-dir=/home/git/gitlab-satellites/..../.git merge-base origin/master source/TestBranch
·· fatal: Not a valid object name source/TestBranch
```