# Assembla Git repo shows latest revision, but does not pull down with clone

Tags: git, assembla

Seeing something weird I cannot figure out.  Another programmer (so I did not watch what was done) pushed a set of files.  When I look at the source files in Assembla, the latest (expected) revision is shown on a file (last alpha-numeric at the end of the line):

```
BlastsController.php 2014-08-12 [name] Ticket # 61  e0af705fff
```

But when I click on `BlastsController.php`, the new code is not there, nor does it pull down with a `git clone`.  This is all in HEAD. There are no additional branches.

If I click on the revision string itself I get a diff view between the revision shown and the previous... so the new code is there in some capacity. And when I do a `git log` on a fresh clone, the file shows one one commit. Yet if that was true, the new code/revision would not be in Assembla at all.

How could the revision I expect show up (which I assume means it was the latest checked in), but somehow it is not the one pulled down in a clone but some other revision?

Comment: Which branch is the latest commit in, and what is your git clone statement?

Comment: Branch is master.  Clone is: 'git clone git@git.assembla.com:repo_name.git'  Thanks!

Comment: There is only a master.  No other branches at this time.  I called it "HEAD" above.  CVS days...

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think whoever pushed the code was in a detached head state.  I was able to pull the commit using the sha1, and then *I* was in a detached head state.  So I'm going through pointing my HEAD at a branch (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin) and merging back into head.  So I think the developer must have screwed up a git checkout trying to update a local file, ended up in a detached head state, and then done pushes.

Comment: The thing to note, and maybe I'll write them about it, is Assembla did not handle this well.  Their GUI just showed a new revision under the master branch.  But then you go to clone and the revision doesn't make it down.  No explanation, nothing.  Nothing indicating the code was from a detached head.  It didn't know what to do with it so it just showed the revision under "master" even though it wasn't really in master.

Comment: `HEAD` can refer to any branch -- the branch you are currently on. But since it's in the master branch, I'm not sure why you can't get it from a git clone. It might be good to check the `.git/config` file in your local clone to see if the remote tracking branch is set up correctly for master.