# How to pull from local branch in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, git, xcode5, branch

So I have a commit to my local branch that has yet to be pushed to my remote. I worked a little after my local commit and decided to go back to what I had committed. I selected the **Discard** **All** **Changes** **.** **.** **.** under **Source** **Control** but it seemed to go back farther then I wanted. I can see the commits under my **History** **.** **.** **.** but when I select **Pull** **.** **.** **.** all I get is options for my remote branch (which still shows a branch that I terminated, so helping me refresh that would be great too but the other thing is more important right now).

Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**Solution:** So what I ended up doing was using `git log` to find the commit that I wanted. I copied the commit number. Then `git reset --hard *commit #*`. The files were in my Finder window but no in my Xcode project, so I went to **Files->Add** **Files** **to** **"projectName"** and added the files. After I assured myself that everything was fixed I committed my build using `git push --force`.

Hope that is helpful to someone, feel free to comment if you have any questions on my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGTheLedgend,

So when you `git pull` you are actually pulling source code from your remote repository into your local one. Instead what you want to do is a `git log` which will show all your commits in the following format:

```
 commit f5c5cac0033439c17ebf905d4391dc0705dbd5f1
 Author: CGTheLegened  
 Date:   Fri Sep 6 14:36:59 2010 -0500

     Added and modified the files.

 commit c14809fafb08b9e96ff2879999ba8c807d10fb07
 Author: CGTheLegened 
 Date:   Tue Sep 4 08:59:32 2010 -0500

    Just simple test for core.editor.

 ... etc ...
```

From here, you want to use the `git reset` command to go to a specific commit. If you do:

```
  git reset --hard c14809fa
```

To make your local code and local history be just like it was at that commit.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: So I used the command that you suggested. It says that my HEAD is no pointing to the commit that I want but the change is not showing up in XCode. I already tried quitting XCode and starting up again.

Comment: Hey CGTheLedgend, ahh yes; I've come across the situation you're in right now; you should read through this answer first (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin) to give you a sense of where you are right now; the steps listed there should work for you; if they don't please reach out and ask me any questions! Thank you for your time!