# Recover from Git Detached HEAD

Tags: git, git-branch

I was fooling around in GitEye by mistake i double clicked on a tag. And my repository checked out to that particular tag and

`git status` give the following output
`HEAD detached at added-MySQL-cnf`. I just want to go back to my `master` branch. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin) and created a new `tmp` branch. Now when i execute `git checkout master` which should checkout to `master` branch it says.

```
git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    docs/make.bat
    scripts/mysql_backup.bat
    scripts/run.bat
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting

git status         
On branch tmp
Untracked files:
    (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ../docs/
    ../scripts/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

and

```
git stash
No local changes to save
```

I have no idea what to do. Can please someone help me i just want to go back to my `master branch`.

Comment: Try `git stash save -include-untracked`, then `git checkout master`.

Comment: `git stash save --include-untracked
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in scripts/mysql_backup.bat.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
Saved working directory and index state WIP on tmp: 96c9a7b added MYSQL configuration file
HEAD is now at 96c9a7b added MYSQL configuration file
Unlink of file 'docs/make.bat' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
Unlink of file 'docs/make.bat' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) n
warning: failed to remove docs/make.bat`  Still no luck.

Comment: Please edit `git stash save -include-untracked to git stash save --include-untracked`

Comment: I can't edit my comment anymore because it's too old, but you're right: a `-` was missing.

Comment: Try moving those three files to a different directory manually, then check out master. Or then reclone the repo.

Comment: `git checkout -f master` worked. Now my repo HEAD is at `master` branch