# Does a commit know its children? - detached HEAD

Tags: git

Do I understand what's detached HEAD is all about in GIT? I see it as follows.

HEAD points to the currently active branch. If I `checkout` (select) an earlier commit in the branch, HEAD's will store the hash of that commit (instead of branch name) - this is the situation called 'detached HEAD'. Now suppose I added a few commits after doing that and `checkout` back the `master` branch (that's where I was at the beginning).

Now, what's the exact reason I've lost the commits I'd just made?
Is it because the commits only know its parents, not children? The solution is to create a new branch in detached HEAD state before doing commits, right? This way I'll be able to reference to the new commits made from that point.

Interesting [source](http://gitolite.com/detached-head.html)

Comment: A commit only know its parent, it can't know any children since the children have not been made so far :) It is a single linked list, one direction. A very nice answer I found recently about the detached head is [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin#answer-5772882)

Answer (score 0):

The exact reason the new commits were lost is because by creating them in detached `HEAD` mode, there is no commit or tag that references them.  Thus they cannot be found by `log`, for example.

To track the new commits you can create a new branch in detached `HEAD` state either before or after you have made additional commits.  Alternatively you could `tag` the final commit before running `checkout` to switch back to `master`.

Note that the commits are not truly lost - not immediately at least.  The `reflog` will have a record of where `HEAD` pointed at all times, even when not on a branch.  However, after a long time it is possible that the unreferenced objects will be *garbage collected* to save space in the repository.