# How do I re-attach my head in pycharm?

Tags: git, svn, github, pycharm

**Update:** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5772882/2734863) seems to certainly be what I need. However when I follow the intstructions I am stuck as to how I can get my develop `branch` to point to my `temp` branch

i.e. How do I execute the following commands in pycharm:

```
git branch -f develop temp
git checkout master
```

---

I was on the "Trying to crop all frames..." commit (`commit f4b641d`) and I needed to go back to the previous commit temporarily just to look around. I did so with `Checkout Revision` and then afterwards I went back to `commit f4b641` with another `checkout revision` though I forced it since I didn't care about lost local changes while.

Either way, I now see in the bottom right of the pycharm GUI (see first image) that I am no longer in the `develop` branch. So I have been developing on the `f4b641` branch and now wish to commit and push my changes in this branch back to the develop branch on github. How do I reattatch my head in pycharm without losing my changes?

The warning dialog informs me I should checkout a branch to avoid losing my work, but if I do that I'll lose my local changes wont I?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend reading the accepted answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin) before doing anything.

Comment: Looks like my reply last night while commuting didn't go through, I tried and am stuck. I have read the link and I am stuck on the "If your new temp branch looks good, you may want to update (e.g.) master to point to it:"

How do I get develop to point to temp in pycharm? See updates in question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ran into this problem again a year later. Pycharm's UI is insufficient so assuming I've checked out a commit and reset the HEAD there (and I want master to be here) run:

```
git branch -f master HEAD && git checkout master
```

Comment: Awesome... this worked for me, substituting `HEAD` for the branch I was trying to catch up with (ie. `git branch -f master origin/dev && git checkout master`)

Answer (score -1):

The problem with detached HEAD in Pycharm can occur due to misconfigured directory mappings. To solve it, go to **Preferences -> Version Control**. Check that the path to the project directory is correct and remove all other mappings marked in red, if any.