# Git checkout to recent commit

Tags: git

I have a total of 24 commits, and I had checkout to commit 15. How can I go back to my last commit?

Note: I have run a lot of commits. For instances,

```
git revert, git checkout, git reset.
```

I don't know my last commit name, id, or even the files. All I know that I have committed, but I am not there.

but I could not go back to my latest commits.

Thank you

Comment: You might want to try `git reflog`. This command shows you the last things you did, with the most recent one at the top. The hash on the left is the commit which was checked out after that action.

Comment: Using git bash, you can issue the following command to get a list of all branches - 
`git branch`

After that, you can issue the following command to checkout the latest of any branch - 
`git checkout <branch-name>`

After checking out, if you want to see the history, you can issue the following command -
`git log`

Comment: Thank you @lucash. after git reflog, I checkout to my latest commit id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reconcile detached HEAD with master/origin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)

Comment: Thank you @Jim, after checkout to recent commit I couldnt push to online  repository. this link helped me to solve my next problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, with help of friends in here I come up with solution. the resean I post this. It may help other as well.

First, I used to `git reflog` to show all my last commit.

Second, I used `git checkout commit_id`

Third, `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit master github/master temp`.

Then, `git branch -f master temp`.

And, `git branch -d temp`.

Finally, `git push --force github master`

Answer (score 3):

`git checkout foo` will check out the most recent commit on the `foo` branch.  If you're working in `master`, you would run the command `git checkout master`.

**Edit:** In this case, you seem to have been committing to a detached head.  You should follow the advice given for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin) and avoid doing this in future.

Comment: It goes to my checkout commit not latest commit. After checkout I have worked and commit,but it not show

Comment: What do you mean by "checkout commit not latest commit"?

Comment: I mean, I had use git checkout 6d15fe9179a22ebb97333cb2fc15c1757d2d29f2. after checkout I have add and committed a lot. Now I want my head should be the latest commit not the checkout commit

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if you are navigating through commits (using `checkout`s) and you want to go back to the latest commit you made

Answer (score 1):

`git log --all`
will show you all your commits
you can git checkout the hash you want