# How to add changes to previous version and save it to branch master

Tags: git

if I have **a > b > c** versions. I want go back to **b** and add some changes So what I have now is **a > b >** **b+newChanges** on master branch, I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What about **c**? Do you want the set of changes introduced from b to c to no longer be part of the master branch? Do you want to save it on a different branch? Also, do you want to still have b itself as a revision, so that your master branch history includes a, then b, then b+newChanges? Or do you want to omit b, so that your master branch history goes directly from a to b+newChanges, effectively combining the changes from a to b with the newChanges in a single change set?

Comment: I want the master branch version to be b+newchanges

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to be the revision _before_ that? Should it be b, or a? In other words, do you want to have the ability to revert to b or not?

Comment: It would be fine if b is the previous version  like a > b > b+changes

Comment: OK, I would advise updating your question to say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
git reset HEAD~1
# make changes
git commit -a --amend
```

This will combine all your changes from `b` and `c` and the new changes into one new `b` commit. If you want to loose you changes from `c` use `reset --hard`.

Comment: It worked but i still have no access to master branch it says ((dc8c622...)) insted of master sorry if that stupid question but i am new to git

Comment: Is that a detached head? Try the 2nd answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't push the commit to the remote, try this:

1. checkout a new branch from the b commit
2. make changes and commit to the new branch
3. git rebase from new branch to previous branch

commands are below:

```
git checkout <b commit hash> -b <new branch name>
#make changes 
git add .
git commit
git rebase <new branch name> <previous branch name>
```

If you have already push the a > b > c to remote, you **shouldn't** change the commit history, just make changes and commit it.

Answer (score 1):

In git, a branch is basically just a friendly name for a revision - keeping in mind that a git revision also includes information about its history. The main advantage of branches over revision hashes is that you can change which revision a branch refers to; for example, when you commit some new code, git updates the currently checked-out branch to refer to the brand new revision you just created.

So in your case, you have (at least) three revisions, **a**, **b**, and **c**. Revision **a** is the parent of **b**, which in turn is the parent of **c**, and the **master** branch refers to revision **c**. What you need to do is

1. Ensure that you have your **master** branch checked out.

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
2. (Optional) If you want to keep access to **c**, you should create another branch that will refer to **c**. You can do this by running the following command:

   ```
   git branch newbranch
   ```

   and that will create a branch called **newbranch** which refers to revision **c**.
3. Reset the **master** branch so that it refers to revision **b**. To do this, with **master** checked out, run

   ```
   git reset --hard HEAD^
   ```

   The notation `HEAD^` means "the revision prior to `HEAD`", and `HEAD` is a shorthand for the currently checked-out revision. (Kind of like a special branch name.) In your case, `HEAD` is **c**, but then after running this command, `HEAD` will be **b**. If you skipped step 2, you have now lost access to revision **c**.<sup>1</sup>
4. Make your desired new changes.
5. Commit your new changes into a new revision.

   ```
   git commit -a
   ```

   to commit all changed files that were already being tracked by git, or

   ```
   git add [files]
   git commit
   ```

   to explicitly specify what files to commit. You have now created a new revision, **d**, whose parent is **b** and which includes the new changes.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, not *really*, but that's advanced usage.

Comment: So can i checkout to the newbranch without adding the current version to statging area i mean to say: git add .

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but if you have any changes that have not yet been committed when you run `git branch newbranch`, those changes will not be included in **newbranch**.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer right here  [stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192) what i did looks like this

git reset HEAD~1

### added some changes and added them to stage area

git branch -f master temp

git checkout master