# Git head getting detached when I push or commit

Tags: git

Hi I am new to Git and I am trying to do these simple steps.

1. First I clone my remote repo from GitHub

   ```
   git clone git@github.com:eldon/Test.git
   ```
2. Then I make some changes in a file and try to stage it to commit

   ```
   git add *
   ```
3. Then I commit it:

   ```
   git commit -m "Initial Commit"
   ```
4. Then I push it:

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```

But then if I check `git status` it is showing *head detached* . If I give the below code its working fine:

```
git checkout master
```

Sometimes it is showing head detached after I commit also.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: You should be using `git add .` and not `git add *`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin

This explains in detail what you may be looking for.

Comment: what is the reason for that @Deep

Comment: @EldonKuzhyelil Because that is correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your local branch is not tracking your remote branch, because you cloned an empty repository with no original content and no master branch.

When you push the first time you should use the following command.

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: what does '-u' indicates in the git push

Comment: @EldonKuzhyelil, In this case, the flag is equivalent to `--set-upstream` which basically tells git that the local branch should track the remote branch so that in the future you can just `git push` and `git pull` without specifying a remote explicitly.