# Fix Git Branching with Detached Head and Unrelated Histories

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, branching-and-merging, git-detached-head

I need to fix a Git repository that has a detached head and 2 consecutive branches with unrelated histories. I have to use SourceTree at work, but I can use command lines too if needed. 
What I have to do is to reconcile the current [Head] (3 on the image) with the [origin/master][origin/head][master] (2) without loosing the commits in between. I would also like to merge (or re-attach) the 2 branches (pink and blue). (I only want 1 branch in total). I am not sure in which order it would be best to proceed: reconciling the [Head] and [origin/master] or re-attaching the 2 branches.

[Git Repository Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyICn.png)

*I had to hide all the names and comments as this is for work and the content I am allowed sharing is restricted. And sorry if this question is not up to the best standards, it is my first question on any kind of forum.*

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin) will help you?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I just fixed the detached head, it was as simple as to checkout the master branch. Now all I have to do is to merge the new branch (with "Initial commit" comment) with the branch that actually contains code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you create a branch label at `HEAD`, then you will be free to checkout other branches without losing any of your commit history (Ofcourse later you can still retrieve the commit histories provided you know the SHA-IDs, but that's difficult to keep track of)

So first thing first, create a local branch at where your `HEAD` is

> git branch develop

*(develop is some branch name, you can give any other name as you wish)*

Now if you see your source tree, you will see both `HEAD` and develop (or whatever name you gave in the above git command). You are now free to checkout `master` branch.

> git checkout master

Once you do, your `HEAD` will now be at `master`. Remember: `HEAD` tells you which snapshot (or which commit) your current code is in.

Next if you want to get the commits of your `develop` branch (branch which you just created above) in the `master` as well, all you need to do is **merge**

Assuming you are in master branch (If you are not, then checkout master)

> git merge develop

(This brings develop branch commits in local master)

> git push origin master

(This pushes those changes to remote/master)

**Tip:**  Instead of **merge**, there is a better option **rebase** available in git. But I assume you are new to git, so its better for you to go through some online material and study about it to understand the difference between merge and rebase. (Or you can ask your peers to explain you)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I just fixed the detached head problem and realized doing so that I was wrong in thinking there had been commits since the head was detached. I now only need to find a way to merge the current master branch with the other one. The problem being they have unrelated histories so git won't let me merge them.

Comment: I have edited my response further. You can anytime merge two branches (despite whatever history they have). But yes, you may need to fix the conflicts if the two different branches are modifying the same files.

Comment: I have fixed my problem by merging with the --allow-unrelated-histories option. I now have 1 master branch, no detached head. Everything is as I wanted! Thanks!