# git: difference between move and change HEAD

Tags: git

> The first thing reset will do is move what HEAD points to. This isn’t
> the same as changing HEAD itself (which is what checkout does); reset
> moves the branch that HEAD is pointing to.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified

What is the difference between moving HEAD and changing HEAD?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we're on `main`.

- `git checkout mybranch` points HEAD at `mybranch`, and copies the contents of `mybranch` into the index and the working tree. We are now "on" `mybranch`.
- `git reset a0b0c0` points `main` at `a0b0c0`. It *also* keeps HEAD pointed at `main` so that we are still "on" `main`. It might or might not also copy the contents of `a0b0c0` into the index and/or the working tree, depending whether this reset is soft, mixed, or hard.

Answer (score 0):

Moving HEAD would mean changing the position in the tree of the branch HEAD points to.
Changing HEAD basically means changing the branch you're on.

> The second important difference is how checkout updates HEAD. Whereas reset will move the branch that HEAD points to, checkout will move HEAD itself to point to another branch.

> For instance, say we have master and develop branches which point at different commits, and we’re currently on develop (so HEAD points to it). If we run git reset master, develop itself will now point to the same commit that master does. If we instead run git checkout master, develop does not move, HEAD itself does. HEAD will now point to master.

Answer (score 0):

The quote describes the case where `HEAD` points to a branch. Suppose `master` points at `CommitA`, and `dev` points at `CommitB`.

Before,

```
HEAD -> master -> CommitA
```

after `git reset dev`

```
HEAD -> master -> CommitB
```

after `git reset CommitB`

```
HEAD -> master -> CommitB
```

after `git checkout dev`

```
HEAD -> dev -> CommitB
```

after `git checkout CommitB`

```
HEAD -> CommitB
```

`git reset` changes the commit `HEAD` recursively points at, from `CommitA` to `CommitB`. `git checkout` changes what `HEAD` directly points at, from `master` to `dev` and from `master` to `CommitB`.

`HEAD` could be detached in the first place,

```
HEAD -> CommitA
```

In this case, after `git reset dev`

```
HEAD -> CommitB
```

after `git reset CommitB`

```
HEAD -> CommitB
```

after `git checkout dev`

```
HEAD -> dev -> CommitB
```

after `git checkout CommitB`

```
HEAD -> CommitB
```

Comment: Doesn't `HEAD` always point to a branch? Your first sentence makes it sound like there could be a case where `HEAD` does not point to a branch; I'm still getting used to the exact meanings Git uses.

Comment: @Bob No. It could be a detached HEAD. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51264681/6330106. A detached HEAD can be considered as an anonymous branch.

Comment: I'm glad that you wrote: _The quote describes the case where HEAD points to a branch_ I fiddled with `git reset <commit>` and found that it works differently when HEAD points to a commit (i.e., when in detached head state). In this case the branch pointer (i.e., .git/refs/heads/master) is not changed by `git reset`. I did not find this information in the docs.