# Can't push after local merge in gitlab

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I am following the gitlab instructions to perform a local merge of a release branch into our develop branch:

> Check out, review, and merge locally
>
> Step 1. Fetch and check out the branch for this merge request
>
> ```
> git fetch origin  
> git checkout -b releaseX origin/releaseX
> ```
>
> Step 2. Review the changes locally
>
> Step 3. Merge the branch and fix any conflicts that come up
>
> ```
> git fetch origin  
> git checkout origin/develop   
> git merge --no-ff releaseX
> ```
>
> Step 4. Push the result of the merge to GitLab
>
> ```
> git push origin develop
> ```

I had previously pulled the release branch, so I started at step 3 on the develop branch.

`git fetch origin` - fetched a few changes in develop
`git checkout origin/develop` - created a detached head
`git merge --no-ff releaseX` - merged with conflicts

I manually resolved all the conflicts, then resumed with:

`git commit` - brought up the commit message editor; saved and closed that
`git push origin develop`

The attempt to push did nothing and replied with:

`Everything up-to-date`

I'm not sure where to go from here. None of the answers I've found so far seem to apply to this. The closest I've found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin), but I'm not sure if the scenarios discussed apply here.

I should mention that I'm using git for Windows and git bash for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key part is:

> `git checkout origin/develop` - created a detached head

If you are operating on a detached head, don't be surprise that pushing a local branch (like `git push origin develop`) triggers... nothing: develop HEAD has not changed.

Instead, update develop:

```
git checkout develop
git pull
```

Then do your merge: `git merge --no-ff releaseX`: resolve conflicts, add, commit and push.

> Is there any way to reattach the head to `origin/develop`?

Yes: make sure your branch `develop` references your current (detached) head.
(Double-check that `git status` is still showing a detached head first)
See [`git branch -f`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--f):

```
git branch -f develop
```

Comment: It took hours to resolve the conflicts, so I'm loath to redo it if I can avoid it. Is there any way to reattach the head to origin/develop?

Comment: @JackA. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: I assume you meant `git branch -f develop` for the last line. That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Yes, I have fixed the answer.