# GIT - HEAD detached

Tags: git

I am new to GIT. I have created a virtual host and setup my project locally. All the branches of the site list out including origin/sprint.  I wanted to switch to `origin/sprint` branch and start my work. (I am not the one who created a `origin/sprint` branch.) So I gave `git checkout origin/sprint` and now it has checked out as follows. `((HEAD detached at origin/sprint))`

I made some changes in that sprint branch too. But I didn't commit yet. I want to know whether it will be a problem if I commit by staying as `((HEAD detached at origin/sprint))` ?

If committing in **HEAD detached** is not the correct way, what are the steps should I follow as I have done some changes in that HEAD detached.

Thank you.

Comment: this post should help you out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)

Comment: As eftshift0 answered, working on a detached HEAD in Git is OK. As you are a Git beginner, though, I don't recommend it: it's a little like taking the training wheels off the bicycle, or walking a tightrope without a safety net. :-) Make yourself a branch name to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem (technically) with being on `detached HEAD`. You are working without a branch because you asked git to checkout a remote branch. If you haven't committed anything and you would rather create your local sprint branch from remote sprint, you can run this:

```
git checkout -b sprint
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/sprint
```

that should do

Comment: Probably best to do the checkout *without* `-b`, so as to make `sprint` link to `origin/sprint`.

Comment: (`--set-upstream-to` - the old `--set-upstream` has the arguments all weird)

Answer (score 0):

> I made some changes in that sprint branch too

No, you didn't. You have committed into HEAD, because it is detached (it is not pointing to a branch but to a commit).

> what are the steps should I follow as I have done some changes in that HEAD detached

That depends on what you are trying to do. If you wanted to work on a local copy of the `origin/sprint` branch, then do that: create a `sprint` branch (optionally tracking `origin/sprint`) and then check it out.

Assuming you just committed your changes on top of `origin/sprint`, you can fix it with:

```
git branch sprint
git checkout sprint
```