# How to use "repo forall" without getting Detached head

Tags: git

I am running the following command to point my repo the some point in the past (for Debug):

```
repo forall -c 'git checkout `git rev-list --all -n1 --before="2020-04-20 01:00"`'
```

and I'm getting detached head which makes it difficult to continue work from that point.

Although there is an excellent review  of what is "Detached head" at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5772882/10556443

and one would argue it's fine as-is, I would like to get all git repo point to master -

Is it possible (at one shot and not going one-by-one and do `git checkout master`?

Comment: what is "repo forall"? seems like it's running some command on all your local repos... just checkout master. `repo forall -c 'git checkout master'`