# I want to access New Commit made to my PR

Tags: git, github, gitlab, signal-processing, gitlab-ci

I submitted a PR and a commit was added to that branch is I pushed.

Please how can I get the new commit to show in the branch on my machine.

Comment: You can use `git fetch` and pass the commit hash

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+update+local+branch

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git fetch` described in the doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch). But be aware that doing so will cause the head to detach.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin) post explains how to reconcile a detached head if required.