# Resurrect lost commits to deattached head

Tags: git, version-control

I have regularly committed my progress and wanted to push it today.
For some reasons I got an error having a deattached head and `(deny updating a hidden ref)`. Now, after doing various steps in order to reattach it my work is gone. I'm unable to recover it or even find these commits. I committed frequently but didn't push. Now I'm somewhat lost on what to do.

Here's the history, I thought I'm on the branch `Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished`.

```
 2004  git commit -am "Removing old logs"
 2005  git push
 2006  git pull origin Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished 
 2007  git push origin origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished
```

None of these worked due to the deattached head.

```
 2007  git push origin origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished 
 2008  git push --mirror
 2009  git pull
 2010  git pull origin Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished 
 2011  git push origin Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished 
 2012  git status
 2013  git checkout origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished
```

Here I'm getting a message, if I wanted to save my work I should create an extra branch for it.

```
 2014  git branch Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge
 2015  git checkout origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished 
 2016  git status
 2017  git pull
 2018  git pull origin Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished 
 2019  git checkout origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished
```

At this point I looked up some solutions on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5772882/2516892
The next steps are according to that post:

```
 2021  git branch temp
 2022  git checkout temp
 2023  git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit master origin/master temp
 2024  git diff master temp
 2025  git diff origin/master temp
 2026  git branch -f master temp
 2027  git checkout master
 2028  git status
 2029  git branch -d temp
```

And I'm trying to get back to the branch I was working at as I'm not on master.

```
 2030  git status
 2031  git branch -f Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge master
 2032  git checkout Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge 
 2033  git status
 2034  git pull
```

At this point I can't find my work any more. The files I've changed are some very old version. (probably from master).
I don't know how to get back to them.

I know I have recently used the `☆` in a debug-message, so I checked for it.

```
$ rgrep -rni ☆
Binary file .git/objects/98/9574bda27235aa00dd6ad2846512c69a87a2a3 matches
Binary file .git/objects/9d/c18eb8bba4d381ad0a96c782fec57928dc92d2 matches
Binary file .git/objects/pack/pack-ca6560ce8bd83b69093cea6fbd492ff9ef1a54c0.pack matches
```

This one is something else:

```
$ ll 9574bda27235aa00dd6ad2846512c69a87a2a3 
-r--r--r-- 1 qohelet qohelet 2244035 Nov  3 17:38 9574bda27235aa00dd6ad2846512c69a87a2a3
```

But that's it:

```
$ ll c18eb8bba4d381ad0a96c782fec57928dc92d2
-r--r--r-- 1 qohelet qohelet 3581541 Feb  2 16:51 c18eb8bba4d381ad0a96c782fec57928dc92d2
```

I have used some tools like gitk to show the last commits. I can't find any. Even the currently created branch `Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge` points to commits done weeks ago (even though I created the branch half an hour ago).

What to do? How would I obtain my changes and commits to a deattached commit?

EDIT (1):

```
$ git reflog 
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge to Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished to Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge to Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge to master
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished to Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{7}: pull: Fast-forward
5ac1604 HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge to Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge to Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from master to Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from temp to master
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from b21832d0d8e5b9b58aa33cd8fd1c11815f635756 to temp
b21832d (HEAD -> Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished, master, Feature_SaveAs_040221_Automerge) HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from bb442dfc6900031ab9a17be4f3ea465a90d7b86f to origin/Feature_SaveAs_Unfinished
bb442df HEAD@{14}: commit: Removing old logs
f7ef5de HEAD@{15}: commit: SaveAs sollte gehen. Test fehlt noch
```

Git show

```
git show bb442df
commit bb442dfc6900031ab9a17be4f3ea465a90d7b86f
Author: qohelet
Date:   Thu Feb 4 09:03:16 2021 +0000

    Removing old logs

diff --git a/DjangoMoP/settings.py b/DjangoMoP/settings.py
index 3e81225..316d976 100755
```

Comment: So, is `bb442df` or `f7ef5de` the commit you're looking for? :-)

Comment: @torek `f7ef5de` is the previous commit. `bb442df` was the commit I did before I wanted to push. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `git reflog` to get Git to spill out the contents of the `HEAD` reflog.  This will get you commit hash IDs (on the left), numbered `@{...}` suffixed names (next to the hash IDs), and information about what made that the commit that `HEAD` identified (for commits, that's commit subject lines).

If one of the subject lines looks promising, try that commit hash ID: e.g., `git show hash`.  If that's the commit you're looking for, you've found it: make a branch name for it.  If not, keep going with the reflogs.  To make a new branch name *`newname`* that points to a given commit hash *`hash`*, use `git branch newname hash`.

Given that you have some data you can search for (or a blob hash ID like `9dc18eb8bba4d381ad0a96c782fec57928dc92d2`—see the output of `git show 9dc18eb8bba4d381ad0a96c782fec57928dc92d2` to see if that's a file of interest, for instance) you can also search the commits in the reflog to see if any of them have, in their snapshots, a file with that blob hash ID.  That's usually less effective than the quick "look at the top few reflog entries" method, but note that `git ls-tree -r hash | grep 9dc18eb8bba4d381ad0a96c782fec57928dc92d2` is a way to find out whether the given commit hash ID *`hash`* refers to that version of the file.

Side note: the answer you linked referred to someone who was in the middle of a `git rebase` when they did stuff on their detached-HEAD setup, and then lost it; the commands you quoted are useful *after* you've set up a branch name to be able to find the commits.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, it does look good! I added `git reflog` and `git show bb442df` in my initial post. I did `git branch Feature_SaveAs_040221_Resurrect bb442df`. You saved my life. Thank you