# Git: Move a few of the last commits to a new branch and then create a patch for them

Tags: git, branch, patch

I've made a few commits and now I want them (say from some commit in the branch) to move them into a new branch, i.e.:

```
 master - O1-O2-O3-X-C1-C2-C3
```

to become

```
master - O1-O2-O3-X  
                   \ new_branch - C1-C2-C3
```

After that I need to make patches for the mentioned commits (C1, C2, C3) so that a friend of mine would be able to apply them on their tree.

As to the first part I suppose I should do something like:

1. Create patches for x -> C3
2. Reset to X
3. Create branch
4. Apply patches

Although [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168370/git-how-to-move-some-commits-to-new-branch) they suggest that I could use `git branch new_branch; git reset --hard X; git checkout new_branch`. Wouldn't `reset --hard` delete my commits?

I'm not too good with git to do it all without guidance. Thanks!

Comment: The proposed sequence works fine because new_branch now points at the commits and prevents them from being garbage collected. More generally, though, if you're not sure about something in git, create a test repository, fire up gitk and try it out. Worst case scenario - you hose your test repository (big deal). Another thing worth mentioning is that you can mirror your current repository with git clone --mirror. This gives you a backup in case you screw anything up. Just run git remote update now and again from your mirror and all will be well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `reset --hard` wouldn't delete your commits, as they would still be referenced by the '`new_branch`' branch.
(meaning that, by a checkout of '`new_branch`', you would recover and see those commits again)

But it would delete any untracked changed in your working tree though, so make sure you don't have any work in progress before typing that command.

You can see a more detailed illustration of that sequence of commands in "[What will git checkout master + git reset --hard do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421717/what-will-git-checkout-master-git-reset-hard-do)".

---

To complete [Stuart Golodetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499449/stuart-golodetz)'s comment, should a git reset had removed or erased any commit, you would still have been able to get hold of those commit with a `git reflog`.
See:

- "[Undoing a `git rebase`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase)"
- "[Undoing a `git reset --hard HEAD~1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1)"