# Git says my repository is up-to-date but actually it is not

Tags: git

There are two git repos in two machines.

Though from the same origin previously, they are different actually because my friend and I operate on them differently afterwards.

Now here is the problem.

I tried to pull from the other repo and I use:

```
git pull origin master
```

`origin` is my friend repo, which is located on the same local network. `master` is his main branch.

But git says my repo is already up-to-date.

They are different with different log info , different commit info and of course files.

So what maybe the cause? And how can I deal with it?

Comment: I suspect you may not be tracking the other remote - try git branch -vv --list master. The output will contain something like "master  450db23 [origin/master: behind 10] ....commit description...". If you are not tracking origin/master, you can fix that using "git branch --set-upstream master origin/master"

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are in a branch (instead of a [detach HEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)D)

See if the result of `git branch` returns a current branch (marked with a '`*`')
If so, see "[Git Push Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729685/git-push-issues/2729765#2729765)".