# What to do with commit made in a detached head

Tags: git, git-checkout

Using git I made something like this

```
git clone
git checkout {a rev number tree rev before} (here I started to be in a detached head state)
//hacking
git commit
//hacking
git commit
(some commit where made on origin/master)
git pull (which does complete because there was some error due to the fact that I'm no more on master)
```

Because it said to me that I can still commit when in a detached head state, I did so.
But now I want to like merge my detached head branch and my local master branch, and then push my bunch of changes to origin/master.

So my question is how could I merge the master branch with my actual state (detached head)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: HEAD has disappeared, want to merge it into master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519031/git-head-has-disappeared-want-to-merge-it-into-master)

Comment: I you could add a screenshot of a commit tree in this state (how a commit on a detached head actually looks like in gitk or SourceTree), that would make this question even better.

Comment: Unfortunalty at the moment i can't but if you can provide on, i'll be happy to see it here. Even if It's must a draw, it will make it clearer

Answer (score 679, accepted):

Create a branch where you are, then switch to master and merge it:

```
git switch -c my-temporary-work
git switch master
git merge my-temporary-work
```

Comment: how does one avoid detaching heads in the future?

Comment: I did this and found myself ahead of origin by 5 commits.  In that case do you just do git push origin?

Comment: strange, I get "Already up-to-date." when merging the my-temporary-work

Comment: Don't forget to delete my-temporary-work with "git branch -d my-temporary-work"

Comment: @ycomp "detached head" happens when you edit the files of an old commit and then commit those without a branch to reference this new commit later. To avoid detached head, don't checkout old commits. If you still want all the files from there, but as a new commit, then you could checkout the directory from the commit, instead of the commit itself.
[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671161/2550406)

Comment: @RobertSinclair you get the `up-to-date` message because you did a `pull` before and therefore are `uptodate` when checking out(=switching to) `master`.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Worked perfectly in 2021.

Comment: But the point is I switched to branch A from detached head. How can I recover my commit that I made to the detached head?

Comment: @WestMountain You can always check `git reflog` to see where your `HEAD` has been pointed. Find the commit id you're interested in there, and `git checkout <commit>` or `git checkout -b <branch name> <commit>` to start a new branch from there.

Answer (score 151):

You could do something like this.

```sh
# Create temporary branch for your detached head
git branch tmp

# Go to master
git checkout master

# Merge in commits from previously detached head
git merge tmp

# Delete temporary branch
git branch -d tmp
```

Even simpler would be

```sh
git checkout master
git merge HEAD@{1}
```

but this has the slight danger that if you do make a mistake it can be a little harder to recover the commits made on the detached head.

Comment: I know this is years later, but thanks for this answer. I didn't consider myself done searching with the accepted answer here because I didn't want to leave around a temporary branch and this answer has the command to delete it.

Comment: If you decide to use the command `git merge HEAD@{1}` you should probably ensure that is the one you want to use by using `git reflog`

Comment: Being able to merge HEAD@{1} saved my life since I had already checked out master preemptively.

Answer (score 40):

This is what I did:

Basically, think of the `detached HEAD` as a new branch, without name. You can commit into this branch just like any other branch. Once you are done committing, you want to push it to the remote.

So the first thing you need to do is give this `detached HEAD` a name. You can easily do it like, while being on this `detached HEAD`:

```
git checkout -b some-new-branch
```

Now you can push it to remote like any other branch.

In my case, I also wanted to fast-forward this branch to master along with the commits I made in the `detached HEAD` (now `some-new-branch`). All I did was:

```
git checkout master

git pull # to make sure my local copy of master is up to date

git checkout some-new-branch

git merge master # this added the current state of master to my changes
```

Of course, I merged it later to `master`.

That's about it.

Comment: This answer worked for me where the others didn't. `git checkout -b new-branch` worked for me. The other suggestions called for `git branch new-branch`, but that left me still in detatched head and the new branch didn't pick up my changes.

Comment: @JessePatel That's because you only create a branch with "git branch new-branch" you have to move HEAD (the current place you're looking at/working in) to that branch by doing "git checkout new-branch". The "-b" flag in "git checkout -b new-branch", means you create a branch before you move HEAD to that branch. Like 2 commands in one.

Answer (score 24):

You can just do `git merge <commit-number>` or `git cherry-pick <commit> <commit> ...`

As suggested by Ryan Stewart you may also create a branch from the current HEAD:

```
git branch brand-name
```

Or just a tag:

```
git tag tag-name
```

Comment: You can find your commit number on the detached head by `git rev-parse HEAD`

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, you could cherry-pick the commit-id onto your branch.

`<commit-id> made in detached head state`

`git checkout master`

`git cherry-pick <commit-id>`

No temporary branches, no merging.

Answer (score 13):

I see everyone almost everyone has suggested a solution where a temporary branch is being created. Now, one needs to admit that whenever this "committed in a detached state" issue arises, it's generally detected after one commit. And creating one whole branch for that one puny commit - Sounds too much, right? Especially in projects where you are already jumping around among too many branches.

What's the easy way then? **Use the commit hash!**

How do I get that?

1. Do a `git log`. You would see something like this:

```
commit 10bf8fe4d17bb7de59586a7abb6db321f0786bb3 (HEAD)
Author: Someone <someone@something.com>
Date:   So/me/day SO:ME:TI:ME 

    A commit message that doesn't mean much

commit a3cd1cedf1962916cdc2945f2bd2b271ec8b919d (origin/master, master)
Author: Someone <someone@something.com>
Date:   Some/other/day SOME:OTHER:TIME 

    Another commit message that doesn't mean much

commit 1bfabbe09c70419070fe29ff1ed276c0207bbe10
Author: Someone <someone@something.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 8 08:38:12 2021 +0530

    Enough reading the example, focus on the answer!!
```

Now, although it looks like a normal case, but when you do a `git push` it would say "Everything up-to-date".

A careful person would see that it's not "up-to-date". `HEAD` is somewhere other than the master.

2. So, what next? Just copy the initial chars of the hash `10bf8fe4d1`. And first, do a `git checkout master`. This would move you to `master` branch. And now since you have already copied the hash. You can do a `git merge <hash>`.  Do a `git log` now

And VOILA:

```
commit 10bf8fe4d17bb7de59586a7abb6db321f0786bb3 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Someone <someone@something.com>
Date:   S/om/eday SO:ME:TI:ME 

    A commit message that doesn't mean much

commit a3cd1cedf1962916cdc2945f2bd2b271ec8b919d (origin/master)
Author: Someone <someone@something.com>
Date:   Some/other/day SOME:OTHER:TIME 

    Another commit message that doesn't mean much

commit 1bfabbe09c70419070fe29ff1ed276c0207bbe10
Author: Someone <someone@something.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 8 08:38:12 2021 +0530

    Enough reading the example, focus on the answer!!
```

Now, the `HEAD` seems to be in a proper place.

Someone might ask, "What if I don't have the hash? I didn't know anything about the dangling commit and just did a `git checkout master`." Don't worry, I've got you covered. You can find the commit hash in two places:

1. When you did the `git checkout master`, `git` had warned you like this

```
Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  10bf8fe A commit message that doesn't mean much

If you want to keep it by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch <new-branch-name> 10bf8fe

Switched to branch 'master'
```

You can see your treasure (`hash`), right?

2. Don't tell me you can't find it. It's right there. But if you really can't, then you can do a `git reflog`. It will show you something like this:

```
a3cd1ce (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from 10bf8fe4d17bb7de59586a7abb6db321f0786bb3 to master
10bf8fe HEAD@{1}: commit:  A commit message that doesn't mean much
```

You see that there's the treasure you were looking for... The hash.

I guess this covers all possible scenarios that could happen in a detached state with a dangling commit. Beware next time!!

Answer (score 7):

In case of detached HEAD, commits work like normal, except no named branch gets updated.  To get master branch updated with your committed changes, make a temporary branch where you are (this way the temporary branch will have all the committed changes you have made in the detached HEAD) , then switch to the master branch and merge the temporary branch with the master.

```
git branch  temp
git checkout master
git merge temp
```

Answer (score 5):

i will give a proper step until push if you in that condition (the commit being detached). the detached mean is when your commit is not is not associated with any branches, it is only associated with the "detached head" state.

First u must to make a new branch, the detached commit will be automatically associated with the new branch

```
git branch temporaryWork
```

And go to checkout to master so u can merge that "temporaryWork". Please consider to check it the list of branch name, to avoiding some error

```
git checkout master
git merge temporaryWork
```

And git will said your file may be conflicted, go to look back your code text editor, and delete the code that you not need.

And commit that change

```
git add .
git commit -am "merging temporaryWork"
```

then delete the "temporaryWork"

```
get branch -d temporaryWork
```

and push it into github.

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Upvoted because you didn't leave the branch littering the repo like every other example I've seen. Simple step but not many answers mention it.

Answer (score 3):

An easy fix is to just create a new branch for that commit and checkout to it: `git checkout -b <branch-name> <commit-hash>`.

In this way, all the changes you made will be saved in that branch. In case you need to clean up your master branch from leftover commits be sure to run `git reset --hard master`.

With this, you will be rewriting your branches so be sure not to disturb anyone with these changes. Be sure to take a look at this article for a better illustration of  [detached HEAD](https://kolosek.com/git-branches/) state.

Answer (score 3):

checkout actual-branch

git merge {{commit-hash}}

Answer (score 2):

When I did the checkout leading to detached head, git actually tells me what to do in such a case:

> `git switch -c <new-branch-name>`

If you do this, it leaves the HEAD branch as it was before detaching the head. It creates a new branch with all the commits made while working in the detached head state, as if you had done `git checkout <new-branch-name>` from the HEAD location. Afterwards, HEAD will be the head of the new branch, as you would expect.

To reproduce/test/understand in more details:

1. creating a testrepo with two commits:

> ```
> ~/gittest$ git log --oneline 
> 17c34c0 (HEAD -> master) 2
> 5975930 1
> ```

2. checkout previous commit 1

> `~/gittest$ git checkout 5975930`

In German, the response from git is:

> Hinweis: Wechsle zu '5975930'.
>
> Sie befinden sich im Zustand eines 'losgelösten HEAD'. Sie können sich
> umschauen, experimentelle Änderungen vornehmen und diese committen,
> und Sie können alle möglichen Commits, die Sie in diesem Zustand
> machen, ohne Auswirkungen auf irgendeinen Branch verwerfen, indem Sie
> zu einem anderen Branch wechseln.
>
> Wenn Sie einen neuen Branch erstellen möchten, um Ihre erstellten
> Commits zu behalten, können Sie das (jetzt oder später) durch Nutzung
> von 'switch' mit der Option -c tun. Beispiel:
>
> `git switch -c \<neuer-Branchname>`
>
> Oder um diese Operation rückgängig zu machen:   git switch -
>
> Sie können diesen Hinweis ausschalten, indem Sie die
> Konfigurationsvariable 'advice.detachedHead' auf 'false' setzen.
>
> HEAD ist jetzt bei 5975930 1

In English, the response from git is:

> Note: switching to '5975930'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
> changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
> state without impacting any branches by switching to a branch.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
> do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
>
> `git switch -c <new-branch-name>.`
>
> Or to undo this operation with:
>
> `git switch -`
>
> Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
>
> HEAD is now at 5975930 1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best solution, (will rewrite history) but you could also do `git reset --hard <hash of detached head commit>`.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way that I prefer because I mean to commit into the current branch and push to remote without an intermediate temporary branch, is suggested by the message from `git` :

```
git push
# fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
# To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
# state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

So my workflow is (assuming I'm on `main`):

```
# make changes
git commit -am "these fixes"
git push origin HEAD:main
git checkout main
git pull

# In my case I'm usually making changes in a submodule, ignore this otherwise
# get back to parent repo
cd ..
git add path/to/submodule
git commit -m "updated submodule"
git push

# all done
```

Now I have pushed changes to the submodule remote, and returned the local state to the HEAD of the branch I started on. The commit history stays linear.

Obviously in this case I'm pushing to main but it could be any branch you are using to pin your submodule state.