# making latest commit master (git)

Tags: git

Here's what I usually do:

```
$ git add . -Av
$ git commit -m "I want this to be master"
```

but when I try to push to remote, "everything is up-to-date" and the latest commit isn't master.

```
$ git branch
* (HEAD detached from f0efe1a)
  added_mongodb_auth
  master
  serviceworkers_branch
```

How can I make the latest commit the Master?

Comment: what is the command you're using to push? are your remotes correct?  after you commit, you do indeed see a new commit in the log (`git log`)?  Are you on the right branch?

Comment: you probably need to merge your changes to master first.

Comment: What do you see if you run `git branch` before running `git add`?

Comment: @jbu I see the latest commit as expected on top of git log.

Comment: @resting: can you provide an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do with commit made in a detached head](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124486/what-to-do-with-commit-made-in-a-detached-head)

Comment: `git push` is not the same thing as `git checkout`, and I have absolutely no idea how you could possibly confuse the two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the output of `git branch`, it appears you're not currently on any branch (called a "detached HEAD" state).

To be on the safe side, first create a new branch (`"save-my-work"`)  containing the commits you've created so far:

```
$ git branch save-my-work
```

Now, to include these commits in the `master` branch:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge save-my-work
```

Now you should by able to push as usual. If you're sure that `master` is in the state that you want it, you can delete `save-my-work` again:

```
$ git branch -d save-my-work
```

---

Tip: Use a graphical repository viewer like `gitk` to have a better overview of the state of the repository.

Comment: git checkout master results in: HEAD detached from f0efe1a
Changes not staged for commit:
 modified:   mongodumps/webapplication/sessions.bson

no changes added to commit
Jorges-MBP:advgest jorge$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
 mongodumps/webapplication/sessions.bson
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting

Comment: Then you need to *commit your changes* first.