# Update remote repository git

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-remote

I am trying to pushed my code on gitlab existing repository
I have pushed in it just few days before and noe I have modified some folders and files in my local repository and when I commit and push my code to my remote repo it is showing 
After commit -> NO changes added to commit
and after push -> Everything is up to date

And when I look into remote repo , nothing is updates, it is showing my old code there..
I think this is because I update my local repository with some folders and files
anyone here has an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: need to see the commands you used, also the output of `git status` and `git branch` would be nice.  See also recent issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054571/making-latest-commit-master-git

Comment: git branch -> *master and for git status -> your branch is up to date with master. changes not staged for commit: and at the end -> no changes added to commit

Comment: I tried as per alert in git bash that git commmit -a -m "mymessage" then only the existing files got updated , not the new folder and files ..how can I update the new  remaining  folder??

Comment: check my answer i've posted. i'm fairly sure that's the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried as per alert in git bash that git commmit -a -m "mymessage"
>   then only the existing files got updated , not the new folder and
>   files ..how can I update the new remaining folder??

From this comment I believe you are running git commit incorrectly... `git commit -a` does not commit untracked files.  If you're creating new files, you need to explicitly add them using `git add <file>`

From the commit help pages:

> -a, --all
>              Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you
>              have not told Git about are not affected.

Comment: Can you all give me Up vote please?? I can not post a question anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to remove `git cache`. Then pull `remote/master`. Then add/commit your local change. Now push to remote. Try following commands.

```
$ git rm --cached -r .

$ git commit -am 'message'     # add & commit your local changes
$ git pull origin master       # sync with remote/master
$ git push origin master       # push local/master changes to remote
```

Comment: Thank you I tried this but new folders and files are not updated ;/

Comment: Somehow have you added new folders/files in `.gitignore`?  `git status` output?

Comment: @Garryp could you `git remote -v` and verify your remotes are correctly set?

Answer (score 0):

So I wanted to add some folders [and files in it] in existing remote repository
SO I did simply to use ***git add path*** and after this **git push --all**

and done!